# What does the construct f[x_] := f[x] = ... mean?

Tags: programming, memoization, faq, design-patterns

[This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2440/effective-matrix-power-like-algorithm) mentions "`x := x =` trickery".

What does defining a function as `f[x_] := f[x] = ...`  do and what is it good for?

Comment: You can also search for "memoization" both here and on SO (StackOverflow) Mathematica tag, to get many examples where this construct is used.

Comment: In short, it means "when x is called, evaluate x = ...". This way not only do you get x back but you also store the value. If you do only "x := ..." then x will remain unassigned.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

It is a simple way to implement [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). The trick is that if you define a function as

```
f[x_]:=f[x]=ExpensiveFunctionOf[x]
```

then when you for the first time call e.g. `f[3]`, it will evaluate as

```
f[3]=ExpensiveFunctionOf[3]
```

which will evalulate the expensive function, and *assign the result to `f[3]`* (in addition to giving it back, of course). So if e.g. `ExpensiveFunctionOf[3]` evaluates to 7, it will assign `f[3]=7`.

The next time you call `f[3]`, it will find that newly created definition of `f[3]` and use that in preference to the general rule. This means it will return the value 7 *without* calculating `ExpensiveFunctionOf[3]` a second time.

Answer (score 93):

[Memoization](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html) is perhaps the most common application, but it is not the *meaning* of that construct.

More generally it is a construct for a function that redefines itself.  This has many uses beyond memoization.  Consider this function:

```
f[y_] := (f[y] = Sequence[]; y)
```

It is used to remove duplicates in a list.  When the function is first called with a particular argument (expression) it redefines itself, only for that argument, to `Sequence[]`.  The next time it is applied to that expression it therefore resolves to `Sequence[]` (because the more specific definition has priority) and the expression is effectively removed.  (Of course it must be [reinitialized](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2423/121) between lists unless you want to remove duplicates globally.)

```
f /@ {3, 5, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3}
```

> ```
> {3, 5, 2, 4}
> ```

You can also write a function that changes its behavior after the first use.
Note the different pattern name to avoid conflict.

```
g[x_] := (g[y_] := y - 1; x + 1)

g /@ {1, 2, 3}
```

> ```
> {2, 1, 2}
> ```

This can even be nested deeper:

```
g[x_] := (g[y_] := (g[z_] := z + 4; y - 1); x + 1)

g /@ {1, 2, 3}
```

> ```
> {2, 1, 7}
> ```

---

### Syntax for memoization

When using this construct for memoization it is often nice to use a named pattern for the entire left-hand-side, e.g.:

```
mem : f[x_] := mem = . . .
```

This is equivalent to `f[x_] := f[x] = . . .`.  In this simple case it is not an improvement, but when the definition becomes longer it has the advantages of being:

- more concise
- less prone to error as there is less code to retype
- a convenient label for purpose of the construct

If one adopts this convention seeing `mem :` will immediately let one know this is a memoized function.

As a contrived example:

```
mem : combinations[set_Integer?Positive, choose_Integer?Positive] := 
  mem = set!/(choose! (set - choose)!)
```

Memoization is not the only application of a pattern that matches the entire left-hand-side and by using consistent pattern names for each application one can impart valuable metadata about the nature of the code to follow.

Reference:

- [How does a construct like `i : func[arg_] := i = an expression using arg` work?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119035/121)

Comment: Very good points. +1

Comment: You can avoid reinitialization if you wrap the application in an ``Internal`InheritedBlock`` like this: ``Internal`InheritedBlock[{f}, f/@ {3,5,2,3,2,4,3}]``

Comment: @celtschk interesting method, although if `f` were ever used outside `InheritedBlock` the result could be very frustrating.

Comment: Well, then encapsulate it, e.g. ``Module[{dedup},dedup[x_]:=(dedup[x]=Sequence[];x);UnsortedUnion[l_List]:=Internal`InheritedBlock[{dedup},dedup/@l]]``

Comment: @celtschk is there an advantage to that over `UnsortedUnion = Module[{f}, f[y_] := (f[y] = Sequence[]; y); f /@ Join@##] &` or do you share it as a curiosity?

Comment: I don't think it has an advantage in this case (I didn't measure, though), hovever it would have an advantage if the internal function itself is complicated/expensive to define (e.g. if defining it as result of some calculation), because this way the original definition is only executed once instead of every time `UnsortedUnion` is called). Another difference is that the internal symbol is still accessible by looking at the definition of `UnsortedUnion`; this might be useful for debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the update!  (Although I would have chosen `NonNegative` instead of `Positive`).

Comment: @Michael Ah well, I *did* say it was a contrived example. :^)

Comment: This is basically the function I came up with back in [1999](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/1999/Jun/msg00320.html)

Comment: @CarlWoll I learned `UnsortedUnion` from [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v4/RefGuide/Union_ex.html).  I am not surprised that came from you.  Would you like me to add a note of credit to [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2423/121)?

Comment: Don't worry, that's not necessary.

Comment: @CarlWoll For what it's worth I now see Leonid already noted as much in a comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/delete-duplicate-elements-from-a-list/2423#comment6476_2423

Comment: @CarlWoll I am fairly busy these days but I am interested nevertheless.  If you don't have expedations of my helpfulness I would like to try it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Go [here](https://github.com/carlwoll/Stack-Exchange-Stylesheet) and download StackExchange.m. Then, ``Get["StackExchange`"]``, run ``StackExchange`InstallStylesheet[]``, save the stylesheet, then use the style sheet.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard very impressive! Is **the more specific definition has priority** realized by placing `f[y] = Sequence[]` before `y`? thanks!

Comment: @jsxs If I understand your question, no.  This is a general property: when specificity is easily ranked more specific definitions are tried first.  So if we have both `f[x_] := 1` and `f[5] := 2` in the system, `f[5]` evaluates to `2` no matter the order those definitions are made.  When specificity ranking is not apparent to *Mathematica* the first definition given has priority.  For example with definitions `g[x_ /; x > 0] := 1` and `g[y_ /; y == 5] := 2` the output of `g[5]` will depend on the order in which they are given.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard now, I see this point. Btw, for the example: `g[x_] := (g[y_] := y - 1; x + 1)` when 1st called, `g` defines itself as `g[y_] := y - 1` and evaluates `x+1` and returns the results, when `g` is called later, it evaluate `g[y_] := y - 1`, right?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Can I use the same pattern name for several different patterns? For example, using `mem : f1[x_] := mem = . . .` and `mem : f2[x_] := mem = . . .` in a notebook. Could you explain a little more about _by using consistent pattern names for each application_ Thank you!

Comment: @jsxs Yes, you can use the same pattern name for different applications within the same Notebook so long as they appear separate expressions.  Crucially this is *not* the same as assigning a pattern to a global Symbol as in e.g. [(30591)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30591/121).  By "consistent pattern names" I merely mean that it makes code easier to read when you follow a naming convention; using `mem :` consistently lets me know at a glance why I am labeling the left-hand-side as a pattern, since there are other reasons why I might need to do that beside memoization.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thank you for your reply. Well, what did you mean by _so long as they appear separate expressions_? By experimentation, I found whether using `mem : f1[x_] := mem = . . .` and `mem : f2[x_] := mem = . . .` or using `memf1 : f1[x_] := memf1 = . . .` and `memf2 : f2[x_] := memf2 = . . .`, I obtained the same output when evaluating an expression, in which `f1[x]` and `f2[x]` appear simultaneously, e.g., `a*f1[x]+b*f2[x]`.

Comment: @jsxs I meant to write *so long as they appear **in** separate expressions.* So as you observed you can use `mem : f1[x_] := mem . . .` and `mem : f2[x_] := mem . . .` in the same Notebook or Cell without conflict.

Answer (score 39):

This is my first reply in this group. So please bear with me if I make any mistake, it would not be intentional, just lack of familiarity with the rules.

Although the replies above mention important aspects, I generally like to view things from alternative perspectives. I'd like to offer a few of those on this question. Understanding is enhanced by viewing the same thing from different angles.

The word "memoization" was already mentioned above by Leonid, you can also think of it as "caching". Consider it as an example of caching data to prevent re-computation. Using the Fibonacci numbers as a simple example, if you have a definition like

```
fib[n_]:=fib[n]=fib[n-1]+fib[n-2];
fib[0]=1;
fib[1]=1;
fib@5

??fib
```

then every time you evaluate `fib@somethingalreadycomputed` M will simply pull the result from memory and not compute it again. This type of construction ensures that you ONLY compute a new result if none is known already for the given argument. In fact, the very fact that the formula is shown at the bottom is exactly how M treats this internally: like a look-up table. You are guaranteed that the order in which `??` (`Information`) outputs the results is exactly how M looks these things up internally. So the formula is ONLY evaluated if no prior match is found. This is how a typical look-up table works in a software system, this has nothing to do with M. You go through your list sequentially, and at the first match, bail out with the result. That's why it's important to have a look-up table in the proper order, which M ensures us. `??` (`Information`) outputs exactly the way the look-up table is treated in the kernel.

Compare this with

```
Clear@fib;
fib[n_]:=fib[n-1]+fib[n-2];
fib[0]=1;
fib[1]=1;
fib@5

??
```

where the intermediate values are not defined, but have to be computed and re-computed every time you evaluate `fib@someInteger`. This can be atrociously inefficient for larger `n` when the function has above-linear complexity.

Another perspective is to liken this to (a particular implementation of) the proxy pattern in object-oriented design. For example, in Java or C# code you frequently find constructs such as

```
public void displayImage() {
       if (image == null) {
           image = new RealImage(filename);
        } 
        image.displayImage();
    }
```

If the image doesn't exist, create it, then display it. If it does exist, skip the creation part, and display immediately what we have already in memory. The visitor pattern in OO design also oftentimes works like this. You check for existence, and you base your next decision on the answer to the existence question. This is the most efficient way to ensure that every unique object is only computed once ever.

Another perspective to think of this is as a combination of computation and data. When you compute something with a formula, you are performing a computation. But when you look up something from memory, you are not computing, you are pulling data and return data. This construction is a very convenient way to combine computation and data and let the system decide which one is to be done at execution time. That's actually a very important concept in software design: data vs. computation. We may not think about it this way because it's so easy in M.

Next,

```
TreeForm@Hold[fib[n_]:=fib[n]=fib[n-1]+fib[n-2]]
```

tells us that the `SetDelayed` is evaluated as the outermost function. Thus, the parentheses are

```
fib[n_]:=(fib[n]=fib[n-1]+fib[n-2]);
```

Now it's easy to see what happens. Every time you call `fib[someInteger]`, we get the result of an equation (`Set`). In M the result of an equation (`Set`) is either the known result (if the evaluated left-hand side is known), or the result of the computation of the right-hand side (if the left-hand side is not known -- yet!). In the latter case it now assigns it to the evaluated left-hand side `fib[n]` and will stored as such, as downvalues are attached to the left-hand side of their assignments.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!  It's great to see you contribute here

Comment: Don't be shy, this is a fine answer (+1). Hope to see more of you here!

Comment: Good one with the QR code... welcome to der Party!

Answer (score 30):

It's ... oh, why not let the docs speak:

[tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html)

(in Doc center)

**Edit**

You may also find additional information by searching for "memoization" on this site. This has always been a great trick to avoid having to re-evaluate the result of a computationally intensive function call. In the above link, it is also used to do recursion.

I'll try to explain things without the added complication of recursion: The basic idea is that when you define a function using

```
f[x_]:= x^2
```

you are using `x` as the name of a pattern playing the role of a dummy variable. The `:=` (meaning `SetDelayed`) has the property of leaving whatever is on the right-hand side *unevaluated* until it's needed, and this happens when a pattern matching the left side is encountered, say, `f[4]`.

To make Mathematica remember things, you can't assign a value to a pattern, so you would normally say

```
f[4]=16
```

Now such definitions are found by Mathematica *before* it looks for matching pattern definitions such as `f[x_]:=x^2` above. So in other words, if I type `f[4]` after having executed the above two lines, my "function definition" doesn't actually have to be used at all because the system already knows the result for the specific value `4`.

The memoization trick now combines the above lines, which would lead to

```
f[x_]:=f[x]=x^2
```

The right-hand side of `SetDelayed` is now telling us to take whatever was passed in through the dummy variable `x` and assign this to `f[x]` using `Set` (the `=` sign). The result of that last operation is that a "non-pattern" `f[x]` with a specific new value of `x` has been defined for later use, and the value that got assigned to that is also returned as the replacement for the pattern `f[x_]` (i.e., the function value in the initial function call).

Whenever a new `x` is passed to `f[x]`, we now get a new "permanent" definition added to the memory so that the function (the pattern) doesn't need to be evaluated again for that `x`.

It's best to play around with this yourself by defining a function along the lines above, and then periodically checking what Mathematica knows about your function by typing `?f`.

Answer (score 20):

It also has another practical side. If you have a **random** function, which

- you only want to evaluate once, **but**
- you don't know *where* exactly it will be evaluated **or**
- you want to declare it *before* the parameters it depends on are defined, **and**
- you want it to be the same after the first evaluation, for any subsequent call,

you can use the memoization trick:

```
initPopulation := initPopulation = InitializeRandomPopulation[args..];

(* lots of computation *)
(* the above *args* (on which the function depends!) are defined only now *)
(* and finally we got to the part where we compute the initial population *)

pop1 = initPopulation

(* use the very same initial population again and again... *)

pop2 = initPopulation 

...
```