# Improve speed for calculating a recursive sequence

Tags: programming, performance-tuning, memoization

I want to calculate following recursive sequence:

$\alpha_{0}=0,\\
\cos(\alpha_{i})=\cos(\alpha_{i-1})\cdot\cos(\beta_{i})+\sin(\alpha_{i-1})\cdot\sin(\beta_{i})\cdot\cos(\gamma_{i}).$

In mathematica 8.0.1 I try to do this with:

```
endRecursion = 20;
beta = Import["beta.txt", "List"];
beta = beta[[1;;endRecursion]];
gamma = RandomReal[{0,2*Pi}, endRecursion];

alpha[0]:= 0;
alpha[i_]:= 
   ArcCos[Cos[alpha[i-1]]*Cos[beta[[i]]]+ 
   Sin[alpha[i-1]]*Sin[beta[[i]]]*Cos[gamma[[i]]]];

result=Table[alpha[i], {i, 1, endRecursion}];
```

The values for `beta` are imported because they are generated by another formula which is not important for my question here. Values for `beta` can be found [here](http://ge.tt/8oL9E48/v/3).

The problem is that the calculation of the `result` is very slowly. It takes about 14s for just 20 iterations! And I need about 300 iterations (times ~10000, because I have several lists of beta values).

I recognized that the calculation is much faster if I skip the `Cos[alpha[i-1]]` in the first or the `Sin[alpha[i-1]]` in the 2nd summand. Then it takes just ~ 0.01 s for 20 iterations. But unfortunately this falsifies my result. I cannot understand why it is so much faster if there is just one time `alpha[i-1]` on the right side of the equation.
Am I doing something wrong? Is there any way to increase the speed of this calculation?
I would be glad about any help!

Comment: Have you tried caching? `alpha[i_] := alpha[i] = ArcCos[Cos[alpha[i-1]]*Cos[beta[[i]]] + Sin[alpha[i-1]]*Sin[beta[[i]]]*Cos[gamma[[i]]]]`

Comment: I am such a *** idiot! Thank you so much for this comment! I totally forgot the caching although I used it some time ago (5 years, perhaps too long time ago). Unfortunately, I did not see this trick when I searched for a solution, otherwise I would not have asked this question...  Thank you anyway! You saved my weekend!
How can I accept your comment as answer?

Comment: @J.M. hmm, in my amazement that nobody had answered this, I wrote my answer without seeing your comment... Hope you were not writing up one also!

Comment: Ok, if you do not mind! Thanks again!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can speed it up by "[memoization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2645/16)", i.e., [remembering previous values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) of `alpha[i]`:

```
endRecursion = 20;
beta = Import["beta.txt", "List"];
beta = beta[[1 ;; endRecursion]];
gamma = RandomReal[{0, 2*Pi}, endRecursion];
alpha[0] := 0;
alpha[i_] := 
  alpha[i] = 
   ArcCos[Cos[alpha[i - 1]]*Cos[beta[[i]]] + 
     Sin[alpha[i - 1]]*Sin[beta[[i]]]*Cos[gamma[[i]]]];
result = Table[alpha[i], {i, 1, endRecursion}];
```

See also the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html) on this.

Comment: Thanks acl and @J.M. for answering my question so quickly!

Comment: There was a mistake: you were importing strings (you didn't convert to numbers after StringSplit.)  I fixed it.

Comment: @Szabolcs yes, I had just realised it and our edits almost overlapped... thanks

Comment: Okay, I'll remove the comments then.

Answer (score 11):

Although you can always implement recursion by hand the way you are trying to do, there are also some specialized functions that are designed to make your life a little easier. In particular, there is [`FoldList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FoldList.html).

This approach is also slightly faster than the manual recursion approach (assuming you start from a clean slate):

```
endRecursion = 20;
beta = Import["beta.txt", "List"];
beta = beta[[1 ;; endRecursion]];
gamma = RandomReal[{0, 2*Pi}, endRecursion];
FoldList[ArcCos[Cos[#1]*#2[[1]] + Sin[#1]*#2[[2]]] &, 0,
 Transpose[{Cos[beta], Sin[beta] Cos[gamma]}]]
```

After initializing the lists as in your example, I need only a single statement to generate the list.

The folding function is what appears in the original recursive formulation, but it is written as a pure function with two formal arguments `#1` and `#2`.

The first argument, `#1`, refers to your `alpha` and its starting value is passed to `FoldList` as the second argument (`0`). The second argument in the pure function (`#2`) refers to the elements of the list `Transpose[{Cos[beta], Sin[beta] Cos[gamma]}]` in which I collected the pre-existing lists `beta` and `gamma` (but in a form that is already pre-processed to avoid having to evaluate cosines and sines individually in the recursion).

Comment: With this particular formulation, one could even simplify the `FoldList[]` expression as `FoldList[ArcCos[{Cos[#1], Sin[#1]}.#2] &, 0, Transpose[{Cos[beta], Sin[beta] Cos[gamma]}]]`. One might even consider using the Weierstrass substitution here, since the `beta` values are all $< \pi/2$...

Comment: @J.M. That's correct - the dot product may give a tiny additional speed boost but I didn't check that.

Comment: Thanks @Jens for this additional answer. `FoldList` is something I have never used so far – that will change now (although the additional speed boost is just small).

Comment: @ Jens,
Let’s say: `alpha[i_]:=alpha[i]=ArcCos[Cos[alpha[i - 1]]*Cos[beta[[i+1]]]+Sin[alpha[i - 1]]*Sin[beta[[i]]]*Cos[gamma[[i]]]]`. How do I have to adapt your solution with `FoldList` for this case? I really have problems to see a solution because now I would need in my iteration the `i+1` element of beta. I would be happy if you could give me a hint again!

Comment: @partial81 The term you changed is the first one in `Transpose[{Cos[beta], Sin[beta] Cos[gamma]}]`, and the change is simply a shift in the index. The fastest way this can be implemented is to use `RotateLeft`:  `Transpose[{RotateLeft[Cos[beta]], Sin[beta] Cos[gamma]}]`

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is also a very nice trick! Now I was able to adapt all my recursive sequences with `FoldList`!

Answer (score 5):

The function runs slowly because each iteration calls `alpha` twice the number of times of the previous iteration.  Thus, $n$ iterations invoke `alpha` $2^n$ times -- exponential run time!  Fortunately, the two nested calls to `alpha` are identical.  If we change `alpha` to call itself only once instead of twice, the algorithm runs in linear time while still retaining simple recursive form:

```
endRecursion = 20;
beta = Import["beta.txt", "List"];
beta = beta[[1;;endRecursion]];
gamma = RandomReal[{0,2*Pi}, endRecursion];

alpha[0] = 0;
alpha[i_]:=
  Module[{a = alpha[i-1], b = beta[[i]], g = gamma[[i]]}
  , ArcCos[Cos[a]*Cos[b]+Sin[a]*Sin[b]*Cos[g]]
  ]

result = Table[alpha[i], {i, 1, endRecursion}];
```

Even so, I agree with @Jens that [functional iteration](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/FunctionalIteration.html) is frequently preferred over recursion in order to avoid hitting the [$RecursionLimit](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24RecursionLimit.html) (or [$IterationLimit](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24IterationLimit.html)).

Comment: Thanks @WReach for answering the other part of my question. Now I understand why it was so slowly at the beginning. And it is nice that you give a link to the useful functional iterations.