# Permanent minors

Tags: functions, matrix

The function `Minors` yields the minors of a matrix. Is there a function that yields the [permanent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Permanent.html) minors of a matrix?

Comment: Anything wrong with the code in your link?

Comment: That gives me the permanent of a matrix, not the permanent *minors*.

Comment: Could you please post a matrix and its permanent minors as an example?

Comment: Make a call to `Minors[Array[Subscript[a,##]&,{n,n}],k]` for any `n` and `k<n`, then replace all minus signs by plus signs =)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For matrices of numbers this is fairly efficient.

```
perm[mat_] := Module[{v, vec},
  vec = Array[v, Length[mat]];
  Coefficient[Times @@ (mat.vec), Times @@ vec]
  ]

permMinors[mat_, k_Integer] := Minors[mat, k, perm]
```

Example:

```
n = 12;
mat = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {n, n}];
Timing[p1 = permMinors[mat, n - 1];]

(* Out[228]= {19.910000, Null} *)
```

--- edit ---

I should mention that I did not come up with this method of computing a permanent. I was fairly certain I had seen it before. Tracking through past email, it turns out that Stephen Wolfram had sent substantially the code same to a bunch of people here, soliciting comments on efficiency (might have been related to his NKS book, I'm not sure).

For symbolic matrices the following may work better.

```
permanent2[m_] /; Length[m]==1 := m[[1,1]]
permanent2[m_] := permanent2[m] = With[{mp=Drop[m,None,1]},
    Apply[Plus, Table[m[[j,1]]*permanent2[Drop[mp,{j}]], {j,Length[m]}]]]
```

That was my one modest contribution to the thread. (This was in 1999; I now realize it was his 40th birthday. Also my brother's.)

--- end edit ---

Comment: Actually, that answers my question perfectly. I did not know you could give a third argument to `Minors`, this is absolutely perfect.

Comment: I'm quite experienced with this, having dealt with an infinitude of arguments when my kids were minors...

Comment: That actually made me laugh out quite loud.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau It'd be worse if they were permanent minors...

Comment: @rm -rf I guess I walked into that. So I'll come back with an anecdote. Where my wife teaches, at first staff meeting several years ago, people were asked to say something brief about themselves. Her remark ended "...and I have three children: my daughter, my son, and my husband."

Comment: @DanielLichtblau She wasn't talking about two kids and a pet. That's as good as you can get

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps just:

```
pMinors[m_?MatrixQ, k_Integer] := Minors[Array[\[FormalM][##] &, Dimensions@m], k] /. 
                                                         -1 -> 1 /. \[FormalM][a__] :> m[[a]]
```

Comment: Heh, that's clever. Thanks a bunch! =D

Answer (score 5):

This seems like a case where [memoizing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/what-is-x-x-trickery) could save a lot of speed.

```
Clear[perm2]

(* The permanent of the submatrix using rows I and columns J. *)
perm2[mat_, I_, J_] := perm2[mat, I, J] =
 If[Length[I] != Length[J], Print["Nonsquare permanent"],
   If[I == {}, 1,
     With[{k = Length[I]}, 
       Table[mat[[i, Last[J]]], {i, I}].Table[perm2[mat, Drop[I, {i}], Drop[J, {-1}]], {i, 1, k}]]]]  

 permMinors2[mat_, k_] :=
   With[{S = Subsets[Range[Length[mat]], {k}]}, Table[perm2[mat, s, t], {s, S}, {t, S}]]
```

I also loaded Daniel Lichtblau's solution. His testing run:

```
n = 12;
mat = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {n, n}];
Timing[p1 = permMinors[mat, n - 1];]

(* Out[43] = {37.6319, Null} *)
```

and mine

```
Timing[p2 = permMinors2[mat, n - 1];]

(* Out[44] = {1.06447, Null} *)
```

Check that the code works:

```
p1 == p2

(* Out[45] = True *)
```

Replacing the dot product of two `Table[]`s with `Sum[]` makes the code a little more readable:

```
perm3[mat_, I_, J_] := perm3[mat, I, J] =
  If[Length[I] != Length[J], Print["Nonsquare permanent"],
    If[I == {}, 1,
      With[{k = Length[I]}, 
        Sum[mat[[I[[i]], Last[J]]]*perm3[mat, Drop[I, {i}], Drop[J, {-1}]], {i, 1, k}]]]]

 permMinors3[mat_, k_] := 
    With[{S = Subsets[Range[Length[mat]], {k}]}, Table[perm3[mat, s, t], {s, S}, {t, S}]]
```

But has basically no effect on speed

```
Timing[p3 = permMinors3[mat, n - 1];]

(* Out[100] = {1.11478, Null} *)
```

Comment: I think you posted this around the same time I added something similar in an edit.

Comment: Ah, so you did.

Comment: (If your timing was a hair better, you'd have sent your reply perhaps slightly before I posted my comment...)