# SetDelayed and avoiding function calls through memoization

Tags: programming, memoization

I am fairly new to *Mathematica*. I am working my way through a number of books. I have been looking at the use of `SetDelayed` and want to confirm that my understanding is correct. I define a function as follows.

```
f[x_]:= f[x] = x;
```

When I evaluate `?f`, I can see a rule for this function. Now each time I evaluate `f`, I see another rule is created for `f`. So by declaring the function as above, I ensure that for any given value of `x` the function will only be evaluated once.

Suppose I had declared functions `f` and `g` as follows.

```
f[x_] := f[x] = Sin[x] + Cos[x];
g[x_] := Sin[x] + Cos[x];
```

Am I correct in saying that, for any given `x`, `f` will only be evaluated once? That is, for a given value of `x`, `Sin[x]` and `Cos[x]` will only be called once; whereas in the case of `g`, each time `g` is called, *Mathematica* will evaluate both `Sin[x]` and `Cos[x]`? Will using `Trace` confirm this?

Comment: Yes, you're correct.  It's more apparent with something like `f[x_] := f[x] = (Print[x];x)`.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to run out of space in the global rule/name space ? In effect each time i call f[x] mathematica is creating a new rule so if i call the function n times i end up with n rules.

Comment: It is possible to run out of memory with this technique, but with most current computers this not the problem it was, say, in the 1990s. _Mathematica_ is very good at getting all the memory it needs.

Comment: see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=memoization and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization and http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html

Comment: Search for memoization on [this page](http://web.ift.uib.no/~szhorvat/mmatricks.php)  There's an implementation that will auto-free memory if too many results are remembered, but it only works for numerical arguments.  I believe there were better implementations somewhere on this site.  Someone will hopefully find them and give you a link.

Comment: This is answered here: [What does the construct f\[x_\] := f\[x\] = ... mean?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2639/5)

Comment: I think that question (and all its answers) pretty much address this question, so I'll mark it as duplicate so that others will know where to look as well. If that doesn't answer your question, please let me know (and the part that isn't answered).