# How to define functions for a parameter-dependent recursive sequence

Tags: recursion

I am trying to generate a two variable recursive sequence

For instance on Mathematica, I did

```
z[1] := {1, 1}
B := {{t, 1}, {-1, t}}
z[n_, t_] := B.z[n - 1, t]
```

When I tried to see `z[2]`, I get a bunch of gibberish.

$n$ is the variable that is iterating, $t$ is just a parameter that I can throw in whenever I want. My goal is to generate a table of terms based on various iterations of $n$. From that, my sequence would be defined in terms of only $t$, then I would like test out various values of $t$ to generate a numerical sequence.

There are two problems I am having: how to define the functions properly, and how to implement the recursion.

I use Mathematica 8.0.4

Comment: (1) Replace delayed set `:=` by set `=` in the first two lines. (2) When you run this, look at the error messages.  Think about how *MMA* is going to tell when to stop the recursion.  (Hint: `z[1]` is not the same as `z[1,t]`.)  BTW, you might be interested in `MatrixExp`.

Comment: I tried using z[1,t] before, but there was no difference

Comment: That's because you need to use a *pattern* in the argument, as in `z[1, t_] := {1, 1}`.  Incidentally, you would appreciate the information you get in a search for [memoizing](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=memoizing).  See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/what-does-the-construct-fx-fx-mean for instance.  Your code is still a little whacky, because `B` implicitly has the literal symbol `t` within it.  It will work with the change I suggested, but if you supply anything other than `t` for the second argument of `z`, be prepared for surprises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two ways to do the kind of thing desired.  You could make the parameter an argument to every function, or have the parameter be a global symbol and not an argument to any function.

**Parameters as arguments**

Put an argument in each function representing the parameter:

```
z[1, t_] := {1, 1};
B[t_] := {{t, 1}, {-1, t}};
z[n_Integer, t_] /; n > 0 := B[t].z[n - 1, t];

{z[2, t], z[2, s], z[2, 100]}
(* {{1 + t, -1 + t}, {1 + s, -1 + s}, {101, 99}} *)
```

**Parameters as global variables**

Make sure `t` is undefined when `z` and `B` are defined.  (I clear any definitions of `z` and `B` as well.)

```
Clear[t];
Clear[B, z]; (* clear previous definitions *)
z[1] = {1, 1};
B = {{t, 1}, {-1, t}};
z[n_Integer] /; n > 0 := B.z[n - 1];

{z[2], z[2] /. t -> s, z[2] /. t -> 100}
(* {{1 + t, -1 + t}, {1 + s, -1 + s}, {101, 99}} *)
```

**Memoizing**

You can often improve performance of recursively defined function if you use a technique called "memoization."  An good discussion can be found [What does the construct f[x_] := f[x] = ... mean?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/what-does-the-construct-fx-fx-mean), cited in a comment by @whuber.  The *Mathematica* documentation has a good introductory tutorial, ["Functions That Remember Values They Have Found"](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html), too.
For example, in the example using `t` as a global variable, the definition of `z` would be

```
z[n_Integer] /; n > 0 := z[n] = B.z[n - 1]
```

See the links for further discussion.

**Discussion**

Each approach can do what you want, and each is probably used often.  The biggest consideration is that if the parameter `t` is a global variable, then generally you want to avoid it being set (no `t = 3` for example).  It might cause unexpected behavior.  Thus I have a slight preference for using the argument approach

*Why `_Integer.../; n > 0` instead of `_`*?

If the definition of `z` begins `z[n_, t_] :=...`, then for an undefined symbol `n`, `z[n, t]` matches the definition and is expanded.  This leads to `z[n-1,t]`, then `z[n-2,t]` etc.  Since `z[1,t]` is never reached, the recursion goes until the limit is hit.   The `n_Integer` restricts the definition to matching only when `n` is an integer.  The `Condition` `/; n > 0` further restricts the definition to positive integers.  This guarantees that recursive definition will be applied only to positive `n`.

*What went wrong in the original definitions?*

What is wrong with the first line has to do with how it matches the third line.  The recursive definition of `z` has two arguments and so it will never lead to this pattern:

```
z[1] := {1, 1}
```

In the second, `t` is a global symbol.  If it has a value, it will be substituted whenever `B` is evaluated, because `B` is defined using `SetDelayed`.

```
B := {{t, 1}, {-1, t}}
```

Another difficulty arises in the different way `z` and `B` are defined.

```
z[n_, t_] := B.z[n - 1, t]
```

The `t` in the definition of `z` is not a variable per se, just the name of the second argument.  Technically, it is the `Pattern` `Blank[]` that matches whatever is passed as the second argument.  It has nothing to do with the global `t` in `B`.  For instance, `z[2, s]` will expand to

```
{{t, 1}, {-1, t}}.z[1, s]
```

where `s` would be whatever was passed to `z` and does not have to be the same as `t`.  (Of course, the recursion will go on until `$RecursionLimit` is hit, because of the mismatch with the first definition.)

Comment: Awesoem it's working just as I expected.

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues here: getting the syntax of the functions correct and then doing the iteration. wHuber shows in the comments a way to correct the syntax of the functions (using pattern matching in the argument of the calling function). You can find this kind of approach applied to [calculate the Fibonnaci sequence](http://books.google.ae/books?id=OuzV1M7b0WIC&pg=PA177&lpg=PA177&dq=mathematica%20fibonacci&source=bl&ots=HC3f4hF9eH&sig=hTmIbEu6Js8arBO_bots_uCTa8w&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ORRGUYSUGMmqrAfN9YDIAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=mathematica%20fibonacci&f=false) which essentially uses the `SetDelayed` command `:=` to do the iteration. While this is quite slick, it is also tricky to get right and does not generalize well.

Mathematica also has several functions devoted to solving iterations. `RSolve` is one, `LinearRecurrence` is another. What I would like to do here is to show a structured way of iterating that can be generalized easily just by changing the function definitions.

Let's define two functions. `b` defines your time varying matrix. `f` defines the function you want to iterate: in this case, each iteration increases the `n` and calculates the matrix multiply:

```
b[n_] := {{n, 1}, {-1, n}};
f[{n_, z_}] := {n + 1, b[n].z};
```

Then the iteration can be done by NestList:

```
NestList[f, {1, {1, 1}}, 3]
```

In this case, your answer comes out looking like:

```
{{1, {1, 1}}, {2, {2, 0}}, {3, {4, -2}}, {4, {10, -10}}}
```

where each entry is {n, {z1,z2}}, that is, the iteration number followed by the state z at that time. Of course you can replace the `3` by any number to specify how many iterations to carry out and you can replace the initial state `{1,1}` with whatever values are convenient.

The above us purely numerical. In the final part of the question, the OP asks to keep the `t` variable symbolic. This can be done by changing the definition of `f` to

```
    f[{n_, z_}] := {n + 1, b[t].z};
```

Now, running the same `NestList` gives:

```
{{1, {1, 1}}, {2, {1 + t, -1 + t}}, 
 {3, {-1 + t + t (1 + t), -1 - t + (-1 + t) t}},
 {4, {-1 - t + (-1 + t) t + t (-1 + t + t (1 + t)), 
      1 - t - t (1 + t) + t (-1 - t + (-1 + t) t)}}}
```

which is of course, growing rapidly in length.

Comment: HUh I could've sworn someone closed my question. ANyways. I tried yours, it worked to some degree. I modified it to another recursion, but it didn't work. The NestList doesn't give me the iterations. I'll show you later of what i mean