# Modify this code using Module and While

Tags: programming, recursion, scoping

I have written a recursive function and would like to re-write the code using **Module** *AND* **While** to compare the timings.

Here is my recursive function for f[n], where 6 n f[n] = f[n-1] + n! for n>0 and f[0]=7.

```
Clear[f]  
f[0] = 7;  
f[n_Integer /; n>0] := f[n-1]/(6 n) + n!
```

Now I want to write it using **Module** AND **While**, I could write using **Module** ONLY, but I am struggling when I need to combine it using **While** loop.
Here is my code using **Module** only:

```
 fm[n_] := Module[{f}, f[0] = 7; f[i_] := f[i-1]/(6 i) + i!; f[n]]
```

Then if I want to use **Module** AND **While**, I get into trouble, here is my code:

```
 fm[n_] := Module[{fw}, While[n>=0, fw[0] = 7; fw[i_] := fw[i-1]/(6 i); fw[n] ] ]
```

The code is not working and I couldn't figure out where does it go wrong. Do I still need to write recursively inside the While loop? And how could I write the correct code?
Any detailed explanations are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: user, I am repeating myself: please use proper code formatting and not LaTeX in a quote block.  See [editing help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help).  While editing you can select the code and press `Ctrl`+`K` to format it as such.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for your comment. But how can I write fractions without using Latex. I didn't seem to find any ways to do that in the editing help.

Comment: The point is to write code others can copy-paste into *Mathematica*.  Write `f[n-1] / (6 n)` etc. instead of TeX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean this?

```
fw[i_Integer] := Module[{n = 0, last = 7}, While[++n <= i,
   last = 1/(6 n) last + n!;
   ];
  last]
```

Comment: Thanks very much. It works. Your answer is very helpful. Now I have learned how to write in different ways.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are interested in learning different ways to write this, here is one that avoids using "variables" entirely, thus removing the need for `Module`:

```
fnw[i_Integer] := 
  Last @ NestWhile[{# + 1, 1/(6 #) #2 + #!} & @@ # &, {1, 7}, #[[1]] <= i &]
```

An expression such as `#[[1]] <= i &` is a [pure function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PureFunctions.html) with a single parameter represented by `#` (`Slot`).  The expression `{# + 1, 1/(6 #) #2 + #!} & @@ # &` is two such functions strung together, with the longer one applied (`@@`) to the second, like this:

```
test = #/#2 & @@ # &;
test[{"a", "b"}]
```

> ```
> "a"/"b"
> ```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is also not direct answer because there is no `Module` or `While` but it is good to know that construct:

```
f[n_Integer /; n>0] := f[n] = f[n - 1]/(6 n) + n!
f[0] = 7
```

[More here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/what-does-the-construct-fx-fx-mean)