# How to calculate solution for each variable automatically

Tags: numerics

Here I have one problem how to calculate x for each y. In this form code doesn't work

```
     y = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6,0.7}; 

  NSolve[-y*16 x^3 - y^2*25 x^2 + 5 == 0, x]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I, too, would probably do it bill's way, but for variety, here's another way.

```
y0 = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7};

SetAttributes[solve, Listable];
solve[y_] := solve[y] = NSolve[-y*16 x^3 - y^2*25 x^2 + 5 == 0, x];

solve[y0]
```

Omit the [memoization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/what-does-the-construct-fx-fx-mean) (`solve[y] =`) if you don't want to save the solutions.  But try

```
?solve
```

and you'll see that the solution for each value in `y0` is stored in `solve[0.1]`, `solve[0.2]`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use "pure functions" like this:

```
y = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7};
NSolve[-#*16 x^3 - #^2*25 x^2 + 5 == 0, x] & /@ y
```

This calculates the `NSolve` for each of the `y`s. You can think of the `Slot` (the symbol `#` and its companion `&`) as a variable that gets filled in by all the values after the `Map` (represented by the `/@`).

Comment: But if the function is large and I can not change y with #, what to do in that case? Thank anyway bill s.

Comment: If you give an example of what you wish to do, we can probably help. There are many ways to structure your code. The best way depends on details of how the functions are defined.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to bill's version, which is probably what I'd do as well, another reasonable possibility would be:

```
Table[
   NSolve[-y*16 x^3 - y^2*25 x^2 + 5 == 0, x],
   {y, {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7}}
 ]
```

Comment: This is so much more readable.

Comment: Thank you Sjoerd C. de Vries. It is working with Table.

Comment: @Sasha, thankfully, `Table[]` can now operate in a `foreach()`-like fashion. Old-timers would have used bill's method, tho.