# Multiple level lists

Tags: list-manipulation

Let there be a list,

```
Sample={{{1, 2, 3}, {a, b, c}}, {{2, 3, 4}, {d, f, g}}}
```

I want to go to individual sublists and do some operation on it.I tried a few things like rule and replace.

```
sam /. {x_, y_} -> {x -> {a_, b_} -> {a + b}, y /. {w_, e_} -> w^e}
```

but I get

```
{{{1, 2, 3}, {a, b, c}} -> {a_, b_} -> {a + b}, {{2, 3, 4}, {d, f, g}}}
```

But I am not getting to individual lists. I want to use only rule or replace.

**Edit**: To make my question more clear I want to specify that I am not interested in one particular list operation. My idea is to be able to traverse sublists using `Rule` or `Replace` and then work on it.
My expected result is like

```
{{{1 + a, 2 + b, 3 + c}}, {2^d, 3^f, 4^g}}
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Does this come close? `sam /. {x_List, y_List} :>  {Total[x], y[[1]]^y[[2]]}`  I am not sure, the expected result would help.

Comment: Your code, `sam /. {x_, y_} -> {x -> {a_, b_} -> {a + b}, y /. {w_, e_} -> w^e}` makes no sense to me.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `RuleDelayed`: `sam /. {x_, y_} :> {x /. {a_, b_} :> {a + b}, y /. {w_, e_} :> w^e}`?  (And a `/.` in place of one of the `->`.)

Comment: First of all my apologies for some what unclear question and @MichaelE2 comment exactly addresses my problem.I am not concerned about operation on individual lists, I wanted to know how I shall reach to it which I got now. A slight modification helps me reach individual lists now like `sam /. {x_, 
   y_} :> {x /. {a_, b_} :> {a /. {g_, h_, f_} :> {g^g + h^h}}, 
   y /. {w_, e_} :> w^e}`

Comment: @MichaelE2: Please post your comment as answer so that I can accept and close this question.

Comment: Thanks.  But as long as the question is "on hold", new answers cannot be posted.  You'll have to edit and clarify the question first.  Then people can vote to reopen, if they wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my answer from my comment, as kindly requested...
Perhaps you meant `RuleDelayed`:

```
sam = {{{1, 2, 3}, {a, b, c}}, {{2, 3, 4}, {d, f, g}}}
sam /. {x_, y_} :> {x /. {a_, b_} :> {a + b}, y /. {w_, e_} :> w^e}
(* {{{1 + a, 2 + b, 3 + c}}, {2^d, 3^f, 4^g}} *)
```

In general given two operations `f`, `g`, one might do

```
sam /. {x_, y_} :> {x /. {a_, b_} :> f[a, b], y /. {w_, e_} :> g[w, e]}
```

Please note that Mr. Wizard has rather generously extended this one method to several alternatives, each of which might be more suitable to a given situation.  Certainly they are instructive in any case.

Comment: +1 since you were here first, even if the question was closed at the time. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Based on your updated question you could use any of these:

```
sample /. {a_, b_} :> {Plus @@ a, Power @@ b}

sample /. {{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}} :> {a + b, c^d}

sample /. {a_, b_} :> {a /. {i_, j_} :> i + j, b /. {i_, j_} :> i^j}

ReplacePart[sample, {{1, 0} -> Plus, {2, 0} -> Power}]
```

Every line produces:

> ```
> {{1 + a, 2 + b, 3 + c}, {2^d, 3^f, 4^g}}
> ```

These don't use replacement rules but I think they are worth a look nevertheless:

```
s2 = sample; s2[[All, 0]] = {Plus, Power}; s2

{Plus @@ #, Power @@ #2} & @@ sample

MapIndexed[{Plus, Power}[[First@#2]] @@ # &, sample]

fn := (fn = Power; Plus); fn @@@ sample
```

See [What does the construct f[x_] := f[x] = ... mean?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/what-does-the-construct-fx-fx-mean/2676#2676) for an explanation of the last one.

Comment: thanks for collective information...!

Answer (score 2):

I would try something like:

```
DeleteCases[Cases[Sample, _List, {-2}], {}]
```

which gives you:

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {a, b, c}, {2, 3, 4}, {d, f, g}}
```

but unfortunately this method doesn't use rules.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess that you may want something like the following:

```
sample = {{{1, 2, 3}, {a, b, c}}, {{2, 3, 4}, {d, f, g}}};
h[x_] := x /. {n_Integer :>   q[n], z_Symbol :> r[z]}
Map[h, sample, {3}]
```

`Map`assigns the function h (replacement rules) to each element at level 3.

> {{{q[1], q[2], q[3]}, {r[a], r[b], r[c]}}, {{q[2], q[3], q[4]}, {r[d],
>       r[f], r[g]}}}

Comment: You can use `Replace[sample, {n_Integer :> q[n], z_Symbol :> r[z]}, {3}]` to fulfil the only thing that OP has stated clearly. But I'm still not sure if this is what OP wants. How it is possible that this question has +2? Am I missing something? ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I didn't know that replace could specify levels. Since you suggested Replace, you may wish to submit it as your conjecture.

Comment: You are welcome :). Notice that above replacements do not do the same thing what your `Map[h...` does. It matches only in this case. My point was to show *levelspec* for `Replace` ;)

Comment: Yes, that's how I understood your comment. The OP's issue seems to be with acting at the correct level.

Comment: @DavidCarraher:david thanks for taking time to write but I was looking forward to first traverse to smallest level and than work on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `Flatten`:

```
Sample = {{{1, 2, 3}, {a, b, c}}, {{2, 3, 4}, {d, f, g}}}
```

and then

```
final=Flatten[Sample, 1]
```

Which you get:

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {a, b, c}, {2, 3, 4}, {d, f, g}}
```

Comment: thanks for replying but I was looking for rules and replace options.