# How to construct this matrix fast?

Tags: matrix

I write a function which is a matrix as below:

```
mat[kx_, n_] := (
   Clear[a, b, h];
   h = Table[0, {i, 1, 2 n}, {j, 1, 2 n}];
   a[m_] := 2 m - 1;
   b[m_] := 2 m;
   t1 = 1;
   aa = 1;
   Do[
   h[[b[i], a[i]]] = 
    t1 (E^(I kx ((Sqrt[3] aa)/2)) + E^(-I kx ((Sqrt[3] aa)/2)));
   h[[a[i], b[i]]] = 
    t1 (E^(I kx ((Sqrt[3] aa)/2)) + E^(-I kx ((Sqrt[3] aa)/2)));
   If[i + 1 <= n, h[[b[i + 1], a[i]]] = t1, Null];
   If[i - 1 > 0, h[[a[i - 1], b[i]]] = t1, Null];
   , {i, 1, n}];
   h)
```

I test the speed of the matrix construction

```
In[90]:= Table[mat[kx, 7], {kx, 0., 1., 1/3000}]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[90]= {1.971113, Null}
```

the dimension of the `mat[kx,7]` is 14, so I test the following randomreal matrix

```
In[91]:= Table[
   RandomReal[{0, 1}, {14, 14}], {kx, 0., 1., 
    1/3000}]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[91]= {0.027002, Null}
```

it is 100 times faster.

**So I wonder if my `mat` function could be 100 times faster.
I know my programming is poor, but I don't know how to code it elegent and efficient.So can somebody help me with it and point it out which is the most important factor that make my `mat` function so slow?**

Comment: Try a simple change `mat2[kx_, n_] := (
  h = Table[0, {i, 1, 2 n}, {j, 1, 2 n}];
  a[m_] = 2 m - 1;
  b[m_] = 2 m;
  t1 = 1;
  aa = 1;
  e = (E^(I kx ((Sqrt[3] aa)/2)) + E^(-I kx ((Sqrt[3] aa)/2))) // 
    FullSimplify;
  Do[h[[b[i], a[i]]] = t1 e;
   h[[a[i], b[i]]] = t1 e;
   If[i + 1 <= n, h[[b[i + 1], a[i]]] = t1, Null];
   If[i - 1 > 0, h[[a[i - 1], b[i]]] = t1, Null];, {i, 1, n}];
  h)`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Thank you! Now it is 0.9second compared to the original 1.9 second. Can it be even faster? I hope it can reach 0.027s.

Comment: You can probably remove at least one of the `If`s and you can always try `Compile`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Compile which part? how to ? I have tried before, not working well. maybe I tried wrong way

Comment: @b.gatessucks Thank you for reminds me to use `Compile`. But I got a littel problem using `Compile`. Can you take a look at the message I drop to Mr.Wizard?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are a few methods.  I am focusing on large values of `n`.  A couple of these return `SparseArray` objects but that may even be desirable depending on your application.

```
mat2[kx_, n_] :=
 With[{x = 2 Cos[Sqrt[3] kx/2] // TrigToExp},
  Riffle[
   Array[PadRight[{x, 0, 1}, 2 n, 0, 2 # - 1] &, n],
   Array[PadRight[{1, 0, x}, 2 n, 0, 2 # - n] &, n]
  ]
 ]

mat4[kx_, n_] :=
 With[{x = 2 Cos[Sqrt[3] kx/2] // TrigToExp},
  With[{a = SparseArray@{x, 0, 1}, b = SparseArray@{1, 0, x}},
   Riffle[
    Array[PadRight[a, 2 n, 0, 2 # - 1] &, n],
    Array[PadRight[b, 2 n, 0, 2 # - n] &, n]
   ]
  ]
 ]

mat6[kx_, n_] := With[{x = 2 Cos[Sqrt[3] kx/2] // TrigToExp},
  SparseArray[{
    Band[{1, 2}, Automatic, {2, 2}] -> x,
    Band[{2, 1}, Automatic, {2, 2}] -> x,
    Band[{1, 4}, Automatic, {2, 2}] -> 1,
    Band[{4, 1}, Automatic, {2, 2}] -> 1
    }, {2 n, 2 n}]
  ]
```

Timings for n = 1500:  (search site for `timeAvg`):

```
timeAvg @ #[1, 1500] & /@ {mat, mat2, mat4, mat6}
```

> {0.3338, 0.1278, 0.011608, 0.01684}

---

Since I have learned that you intend to apply the function for a fixed `n` and a changing `kx` it does make sense to compile the generated array and substitute `kx` values afterward.  I would do it like this:

```
mem : matC[n_Integer?Positive] :=
  mem = Block[{kx}, Compile[{kx}, mat2[kx, n] // Evaluate]]
```

Now:

```
Table[matC[7][kx], {kx, 0`, 1`, 1`/3000}] // timeAvg
matC[7] /@ Range[0`, 1`, 1`/3000]         // timeAvg
```

> 0.03496
>
> 0.01684

The memoization keeps the form with `Table` from being very slow, but it is still not as fast as `Map`.  Even though `matC[7]` will evaluate to a memoized compiled function after the first call it is still called 3,000 times in `Table`, whereas with `Map` it evaluates once, and then this compiled function is directly applied to each value in the range.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Wizard! you always have many clever methods. BTW, I was inspired by b.gatessucks to use `Compile`. If I compile specific dimension(e.g. `matcompile = Compile[{kx}, Evaluate[mat[kx, 7]]]`,then `Table[mat[kx, 7], {kx, 0., 1., 1/3000}]`only takes 0.05s, and it is 10times faster than mat4 if n=7 )but I tried to make it general depending to dimension. So I write `matcompile2[m_] := Compile[{kx}, Evaluate[mat[kx, m]]]`. But of course this won't work! So how to do it? Do you have any idea?

Comment: @matheorem I'll try to take a look at that later today or tomorrow.

Comment: Hello, Mr.Wizard. Have you have any idea now? If you're busy, it doesn't matter, I can wait.

Comment: @matheorem I'm sorry, I forgot to come back to this and I'm just going to bed.  Remind me *again* later.

Comment: Hi, Mr.Wizard! just a remind, maybe you have got an idea

Comment: @matheorem Is your use always in `Table` as you show or is that merely an example?  Put another way, is the function for a fixed *n* value going to be called sequentially with multiple *kx* values?  Or is it going to be used "randomly" on various *kx*, *n* pairs?

Comment: Actually, I am gonna NIntegrating one of the matrix element with variable kx under fixed n

Comment: @matheorem Okay, then compiling as you did should be applicable.  You can memoize it if you don't mind the extra memory consumption.  I'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: @matheorem I updated my answer.  Let me know if you have trouble applying it to `NIntegrate` -- I'm not quite sure what you have in mind there.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I became busy yesterday. you  method works. But I don't understand the syntax `mem : matC[n_Integer?Positive] :=
  mem =` . never seen it before

Comment: @matheorem Sorry, I didn't get notification of this comment.  Please see [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2676/121); it's my proposed standard for memoization, which is explained in considerable detail [here, by Leonid](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25150/121).  By the way, I notice that you didn't Accept this answer; can I do anything to improve it?