# Piecewise function with user-input interval

Tags: functions, programming, evaluation

I would like define a function `g[data,bins,x]` which is a piecewise constant function taking value `data[[i]]` in the range `bins[[i]][[1]] < x ≤ bins[[i]][[2]]`. The difficulty is that I'd like `data` and `bins` to be lists that are input by the user. *Mathematica* seems to throw errors because the argument of `Piecewise` doesn't appear to be a list of pairs.

Here's an example with explicit values that works:

```
f[x_] :=
 Evaluate@Piecewise[
   Map[
    {#[[1]], #[[2]][[1]] < x <= #[[2]][[2]] } &, 
    Transpose[{{1, 2, 3}, {{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}}}]
    ]
   ]
```

However, when I try to define a general function:

```
g[data_, bins_, x_] :=
 Evaluate@Piecewise[
   Map[
    {#[[1]], #[[2]][[1]] < x <= #[[2]][[2]] } &, 
    Transpose[{data, bins}]
    ]
   ]
```

I get several errors because *Mathematica* doesn't know if `{data,bins}` can be transposed. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to remove `Evaluate` from the definition of `g`. This way, you're not forcing *Mathematica* to transpose something that is unknown (at this point). The natural evaluation mechanism of `SetDelayed` is sufficient to perform the transpose only when the function is actually called (at which point, it is known if `data` and `bins` can be transposed or not).

However, the drawback of this is that you end up transposing `{data, bins}` for *every* function call. While `Transpose` is usually an efficient and fast operation, this could easily be a significant bottleneck for more expensive functions. To do this the "right way" (there are many such), we could do the following:

```
gg[data_, bins_] := gg[data, bins] = 
    Function[x, Evaluate@
        Piecewise[Map[{#[[1]], #[[2]][[1]] < x <= #[[2]][[2]]} &, Transpose[{data, bins}]]]
    ]
```

For each pair of `data` and `bins`, the piecewise function is computed once (and the result memoized) and a pure function is returned. You can then call this function with a variable `x` to get:

```
gg[{1, 2, 3}, {{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}}][x]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain how the `gg[data_,bins]:=gg[data,bins]=...` line works? I'm not used to seeing both a delayed and an immediate definition for the same object in the same line.

Comment: @Flip It's an idiom/construct called "memoization". See [What does the construct f\[x\_\] := f\[x\] = ... mean?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2639) for more details.