# How to expand the size of the matrix automatically?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a matrix in 2x2

```
a ={{x, y}, {z, u}}
```

I want to expand this matrix 3x3

```
b ={{x, y, y}, {z, u, x}, {z, x, u}}
```

4x4

```
c ={{x, y, y, y}, {z, u, x, x}, {z, x, u, x}, {z, x, x, u}}
```

5x5

```
d ={{x, y, y, y, y}, {z, u, x, x, x}, {z, x, u, x, x}, {z, x, x, u, x}, {z, x, x, x, u}}
```

and soon...

Basically, I am adding a row and column each time. How to do this automatically, without writing each time?

---

**Edit:**

Now consider x, y,z and u are also 2x2 matrices.

Lets

```
x={{0,1},{1,0}}, y={{1,1},{1,0}}, z={{1,0},{1,1}}
```

and

```
 u = {{p,q},{r,s}}.
```

How I can get a,b,c and d (defined above) in this case?

Comment: At the end you want the resulting matrix to be NxN or NxNx2x2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Final answer:

```
f3[n_] := Module[{m, x, y, z, u},
  m = Normal@SparseArray[Band[{2, 2}] -> u, {n, n}, x];
  m[[2 ;;, 1]] = z;
  m[[1, 2 ;;]] = y;
  x = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}};
  y = {{1, 1}, {1, 0}};
  z = {{1, 0}, {1, 1}};
  u = {{p, q}, {r, s}};
  ArrayFlatten[m]
  ]

f3[6] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

---

First answer,

For example:

```
 f[2] = {{x, y}, {z, u}};
 f[n_] := f[n] = ReplacePart[ArrayPad[f[n - 1], {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, x],
                             {{-1, -1} -> u, {1, -1} -> y, {-1, 1} -> z}]
```

You may be interested in [explanation of `f[n_]:=f[n]=...` construct](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2639/5478)

I chose this way becasue you've said you are expanding an array each time adding one row and column. So this is quite nautral approach in such case.

If you are not interested in mediate results, but only in `f[2]` and `f[15]` for example, belisarius solution is a way to go.

First response to edit:

second code, more safe approach:

```
f2[n_] := Module[{m, x, y, z, u},
  m = Nest[ ReplacePart[ ArrayPad[#, {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, x], 
                         {{-1, -1} -> u, {1, -1} -> y, {-1, 1} -> z}] &, 
            {{x, y}, {z, u}}, n - 2];
  x = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}};
  y = {{1, 1}, {1, 0}};
  z = {{1, 0}, {1, 1}};
  u = {{p, q}, {r, s}};
  ArrayFlatten[m]
  ]

f2[5] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: @santosh I've added an explanation that I have not time to do yesterday.

Comment: @kuba...thanks. I was familiar with memorization thing. If I want my matrix a = {{x,x},{x,u}}; to b = {{x, x, x}, {x, u, u}, {x, x, x}} and so on...

Comment: @Kuba, you can avoid the tricky requirement that `x,y,z,u` be `Clear`ed by using substitutions instead of assignment, as in my answer below.

Comment: @evanb Good point :) +1. I've provided an alternative way too. It was clearly not safe enough.

Answer (score 4):

```
f[n_] := ArrayPad[{{x, y}, {z, x}}, {0, n - 2}, "Fixed"] + 
         DiagonalMatrix[Join[{0}, ConstantArray[u - x, n - 1]]]
f[5] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
f1[n_] := Join[{x}, ConstantArray[y, n - 1]]
frest[n_] := Join[{z}, #] & /@ Permutations[Join[{u}, ConstantArray[x, n - 2]], {n - 1}]
fAll[n_] := Join[{f1[n]}, frest[n]]
MatrixForm[fAll[5]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: If x, y, z, u is itself a 2x2 matrices. Then How to write this form??

Answer (score 3):

Start with the n x n matrix f[n] given by (for example, belisarius' code):

```
f[n_] := ArrayPad[{{x, y}, {z, x}}, {0, n - 2}, "Fixed"] + 
     DiagonalMatrix[Join[{0}, ConstantArray[u - x, n - 1]]]
```

And evaluate

```
substitutions = {
    x -> {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}, 
    y -> {{1, 1}, {1, 0}}, 
    z -> {{1, 0}, {1, 1}},  
    u -> {{p, q}, {r, s}}
}
```

If you are looking for a n x n x 2 x 2 object (that is, a matrix whose entries are each 2x2 matrices), then what you want is:

```
f[n]/.substitutions

(* f[3]/.substitutions

     yields

 {{  { {0, 1}, {1, 0} }, { {1, 1}, {1, 0} }, { {1, 1}, {1, 0} }  },
  {  { {1, 0}, {1, 1} }, { {p, q}, {r, s} }, { {0, 1}, {1, 0} }  }, 
  {  { {1, 0}, {1, 1} }, { {0, 1}, {1, 0} }, { {p, q}, {r, s} }  }} 
*)
```

while if you are looking for a (2n) x (2n) matrix where each entry is a number, then likely what you desire is

```
ArrayFlatten[ f[n]/.substitutions ]

(* ArrayFlatten[ f[3]/.substitutions ]

    yields

{{0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
 {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, 
 {1, 0, p, q, 0, 1},
 {1, 1, r, s, 1, 0},
 {1, 0, 0, 1, p, q},
 {1, 1, 1, 0, r, s}}
*)
```