# Padding of matrix

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, padding

I want to do padding of matrix

```
a = {{x,x},{x,u}};
```

to

```
b = {{x, x, x}, {x, u, u}, {x, x, x}}

c = {{x, x, x, x}, {x, u, u, u}, {x, x, x, x}, {x, x, x, x}}
```

and soon...

How I can automatically do this?

Comment: You can use `ArrayFlatten`.

Comment: Do all subsequent elements have only THREE rows?

Comment: Isn't it very similar to your other question? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43071/193

Comment: @Kuba In fact the OP added a third element showing that the result should always be a square matrix. He hasn't be very outspoken, though. The problem I find with this question is that the OP already asked one of these (where your answer is quite good) but isn't trying with the hints given there (ArrayPad, etc)

Comment: @belisarius If you are ok with that then I should be too :P Yes, that's often a problem, their loss if they don't want to understand the code :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must confess to being confused about the ultimate aim. I, therefore, am sorry if these speculations miss the mark.

If the aim is to progressively pad right with the last element of every list then:

```
g[s_, n_] := PadRight[#, n, Last@#] & /@ s
```

Repeatedly applying:

```
Column[Table[g[a, j], {j, 3, 6}]]
```

yields:

[image]

If the intent is to sequential pad right with the first element then pad right with the last element of each subset then:

```
f[s_] := With[{w = First[s]}, 
   ReleaseHold[PadRight[s, Length[s] + 1, Hold[w]]]];
```

You can get lists:

```
FoldList[g[f[#1], #2] &, a, Range[3, 6]]
```

[image]

If the aim is just to expand first list then apply g:

```
Table[g[f[a], j], {j, 3, 6}]
```

[image]

The latter seems to be consistent with outcome presented. However, I may have misunderstood intent.

Comment: how to write only this out of full fold list: {{x, x, x, x}, {x, u, u, u}, {x, x, x, x}, {x, x, x, x}}

Comment: Thanks...I want this....FoldList[g[f[#1], #2] &, a, Range[3, 6]][[n]] // MatrixForm,   n=1,2,3...

Answer (score 3):

You might use:

```
a = {{x, x}, {x, u}};

{#, #2, #} & @@ ArrayPad[a, {0, {0, 3}}, "Fixed"]
```

> ```
> {{x, x, x, x, x}, {x, u, u, u, u}, {x, x, x, x, x}}
> ```

Comment: LOL - this was flagged as a "low quality post" - I guess the clever filter is broken.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  thank you again for educating...`ArrayPad`. I am still uncertain about ultimate aim.

Answer (score 1):

```
base = {{x, x}, {x, u}, {x, x}}

pads = Rest@NestList[Function[arg, PadRight[#, Length@# + 1, Last@#] & /@ arg],base, 4];
```

Each entry of `pads` is one more level of padding.

Change the `4` in the `NestList` to however many different levels of padding you want produced.

Perhaps a bit "cleaner", same results:

```
Rest@NestList[ArrayPad[#, {{0, 0}, {0, 1}}, "Fixed"] &, base, 4]
```