# Store a value in an element outside of the matrix (as in Matlab)

Tags: list-manipulation, matlab

Suppose that I have the matrix

```
A = {{8, 1, 6}, {3, 5, 7}, {4, 9, 2}};
```

In Matlab/Octave one may store a value in an element outside of the matrix whose size increases to accommodate the newcomer:

```
>> A = magic(3);
>> A(4,5) = 17;
>> A

A =

     8     1     6     0     0
     3     5     7     0     0
     4     9     2     0     0
     0     0     0     0    17
```

How is possible to achieve a similar behavior in Mathematica?

Comment: There is no direct way to do this in Mathematica. Not build in. Must write some code. Also see this [how-to-expand-the-size-of-the-matrix-automatically](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43071/how-to-expand-the-size-of-the-matrix-automatically)

Comment: @Nasser: Thanks!

Comment: This can be done with `ArrayRules` and `SparseArray` or with `ArrayPad` (or other padding functions.) Which solution to use depends on what size of matrices you are going to deal with. Also, this way of increasing dense matrices might be seen as a bad practice from certain viewpoints.

Comment: @AntonAntonov Thanks a lot. The suggested link contains a relevant comment.