# will the same result be evaluated twice per evaluation?

Tags: evaluation

here is the silly question of mine,

if `mathematica` takes `3` seconds to evaluate the function `f[3]`
then I plug the this value `f[3]` into a new function `g[f[3],f[3]]`, Let's ignore the evaluation time for the new function `g`, how long does it take for `g[f[3],f[3]]`, 3 seconds or 6 seconds?

if it is 6 seconds, how can I make `mathematica` temporarily to remember the value of `f[3]`

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/With.html) to define temporary constants.

```
With[{a=f[3]}, g[a,a]]
```

[Memoization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2639/12) is also worth mentioning but keep in mind that once a value is remembered, it won't be forgotten (until to explcitly clear it).  I.e. when you use memoization, Mathematica will remember permanently (not temporarily).

Answer (score 7):

`With` keeps the code clear for longer cases but sometimes I'd do:

```
g[#,#] & @ f[3]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
ClearSystemCache[];
$RecursionLimit = Infinity;
fibonacci[1] = 1; fibonacci[2] = 1;
fibonacci[i_] := fibonacci[i] = fibonacci[i - 1] + fibonacci[i - 2];
fibonacci[20000]; // AbsoluteTiming
fibonacci[20000]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.135008, Null}*)
(*{0., Null}*)
```