# Is there a way to use Table[] without having to calculate my function twice?

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm trying to use Table[] more to be more in the spirit of Mathematica. So for example, I might replace this piece of code:

```
MySimpleFn[a_] := (
  Return[a^5];)

myList = {};
Do[fnOutput = MySimpleFn[i]; 
  AppendTo[myList, {i, fnOutput}];, {i, 5}];
```

With the more efficient

```
MySimpleFn[a_] := (
  Return[a^5];)

Table[{i, MySimpleFn[i]}, {i, 5}]
```

But now let's say instead of MySimpleFn[], it's a function that takes a significant amount of time to calculate, MyHugeMessyLongFn[], and instead of one return value, it returns a pair, {a,b}.

Now, I know how I'd avoid calling the function twice with a loop, just:

```
myList = {};
Do[
fnOutput = MyHugeMessyLongFn[i];
fnOutput1 = fnOutput[[1]]; 
fnOutput2 = fnOutput[[2]]; 
  AppendTo[myList, {i, fnOutput1,fnOutput2}];, {i, 5}];
```

But how can I do this with Table[]? If I did

```
 Table[{i, MyHugeMessyLongFn[i][[1]], MyHugeMessyLongFn[i][[2]]}, {i, 5}]
```

I assume it would call it twice, right? Is there a way to use table for more extended operations, essentially?

Comment: Although the question is about basic issues, I think it shows a great effort in trying to overcome the problem. Good work! BTW, I believe you can try reading this for some general Mma programming considerations: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/193

Comment: [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50441/5478)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to `Flatten` each row in the `Table` result to get the form you are looking for.  Use the same kind of expression that you are using for `MySimpleFn` but flatten the rows.

```
Table[{i, MyHugeMessyLongFn[i]} // Flatten, {i, 5}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the myriad of ways of better vectorising your task, what you are probably looking for is `With`.  For example,

```
With[{s = MyHugeMessyLongFn[i]}, {s, 2s, First @ s}]
```

This can be used anywhere, including within a `Table`.  It is just a scoped assignment to the variable s. You could have an unscoped version too:

```
(s = MyHugeMessyLongFn[i]; {s, 2s, First @ s})
```

But this is generally considered bad programming (it overwrites any existing value of s, and retains the assignment after you are done).

Answer (score 2):

Another mm-ish way to approach this is to memoize the function (note the ":=: and "="):

```
MyHugeMessyLongFn[a_]:=MyHugeMessyLongFn[a]=(someTimeConsumingStuff);
```

and then do as you suggested:

```
Table[{i, MyHugeMessyLongFn[i][[1]], MyHugeMessyLongFn[i][[2]]}, {i, 5}]
```

Your function will be called twice, but the second time it will just remember its value from the first time.

BTW, you might as well get `MyHugeMessyLongFn` to return a triplet that starts with `{a,...}` and then do

```
Table[MyHugeMessyLongFn[i], {i, 5}]
```

which can be written as

```
MyHugeMessyLongFn /@ Range@5
```

Answer (score 2):

This question really amounts to: how can one manipulate lists in *Mathematica*?  The most popular [tag](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags) is in fact [list-manipulation](/questions/tagged/list-manipulation) so there are a myriad of examples available to you.

Other than [memoization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html) as proposed by A.G. all methods rely on calling the function only once, then doing something with the expression that is returned.  You can manipulate each element at the first [level](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15567/121) of a returned expression (i.e. elements of a list) by [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html)-ing a [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) to it:

```
bar[#2, z, #1, #1 + #2] & @@ {one, two}
```

> ```
> bar[two, z, one, one + two]
> ```

- Here `{one, two}` would be the output of your `MyHugeMessyLongFn`
- `bar[#2, z, #1, #1 + #2]` is the body of the anonymous `Function` defined with `&`; it is the output wish to create
- `@@` is short for [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html).
- Note that every appearance of `#1` has been replaced with the first element of `{one, two}` and every appearance of `#2` with the second element.  These are known as [`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) expressions.

Another method that is more general, allowing you to simultaneously address elements at different levels of a returned expression is to use [destructuring](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8382/mathematica-destructuring/8399#8399).  This has a potential clarity advantage as well because parts are named rather than numbered.  Example:

```
{one, two} /. {a_, b_} :> bar[b, z, a, a + b]
```

> ```
> bar[two, z, one, one + two]
> ```

- Here `{one, two}` again represents the output of your long function
- `/.` is the short form of [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html).
- `{a_, b_}` is a pattern (using [`Blank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html)) that matches the output of your long function; it is the left hand side of a replacement rule
- `:>` is the short form of [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html)
- `bar[b, z, a, a + b]` is the body of the replacement rule
- Note that every appearance of `a` in the body is replaced with `one` and every `b` with `two`.

The methods above are the ones that I prefer but if you find them confusing you can also use [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html) to name your output and then use [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) which you appear to be familiar with:

```
With[{r = {one, two}},
  bar[r[[2]], z, r[[1]], r[[1]] + r[[2]]]
]
```

> ```
> bar[two, z, one, one + two]
> ```

Personally I find this harder to read due to all the brackets but you may disagree.

Answer (score 1):

This is more Mathematica-ish:

```
MyHugeMessyLongFn[x_] := {2 x, 3 x}
myList = {#, MyHugeMessyLongFn@#} & /@ Range@5

(* {{1, {2, 3}}, {2, {4, 6}}, {3, {6, 9}}, {4, {8, 12}}, {5, {10, 15}}}
*)
```

Comment: Or `SetAttributes[MyHugeMessyLongFn, Listable];
Transpose[{Range[5], MyHugeMessyLongFn@Range[5]}]`