# How to speed up minimization of function

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning

I have the fallowing code (the functions within that code are replaced by simpler ones, but the code structure is identical):
$$$$

```
g[x_, y_, z_] := x^2 + y^2 + z^2;
f[x_, y_, z_] := (buffer = Minimize[g[x, y, z], x];
   xmin = x /. buffer[[2]];
   g[xmin, y, z]);

Plot3D[f[x, y, z], {y, 0, 4}, {z, 0, 4}, PlotPoints -> 2]
```

It takes my computer about 7 seconds to process that code. With my actual functions it takes several minutes. This is only one step in a longer chain of steps my program needs to process.

Is there a way to speed that step up? Maybe something faster than using the function Minimize.

$$$$
$$$$
If i modify my code like this:

```
 g[x_, y_, z_] := x^2 + y^2 + z^2;
 f[x_, y_, z_] := (buffer = Minimize[g[x, y, z], x];
       xmin = x /. buffer[[2]];
       g[xmin, y, z]);    
Plot3D[f[x, y, z], {y, 0, 4}, {z, 0, 4}, PlotPoints -> 2,
             RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x + y < 3]]
```

$$$$

The result is what i want, but it actually takes more time, even though in the resulting plot are less data points. I assume mathematica plots first my function and then it cuts with RegionFunction in my plot. Is there a way to make Mathematica just plot the resulting area and not plot the area that is later cut out anyway?

I've tried it like this:

```
 g[x_, y_, z_] := x^2 + y^2 + z^2;
 f[x_, y_, z_] := (buffer = Minimize[g[x, y, z], x];
       xmin = x /. buffer[[2]];
       g[xmin, y, z]);    
Plot3D[f[x, y, z], {y, 0, 4}, {z, 0, 4 - y}, PlotPoints -> 3]
```

$$$$

But the resulting plot doesn't exactly look like the one resulting using RegionFunction, it looks abit more 'bumpy'. So i've increased the PlotPoints from 2 to 3, then the resulting plot looks pretty much like the one with RegionFunction. But the Problem is, now plotting takes longer then with RegionFunction ;)

$$$$
Thanks for your help.

$$$$
$$$$
Your answeres (using the function Evaluate[]) helped me solve the problem for the above described situation. However it does not work with my actual functions, so i have to write them down here after all.

```
bindeaa[e0_] := e0;
c[e0_] := 40 e0;
bindeab[e0_] := 1.27 e0; 

alpha[gamma_, p_, epsilon_] := p (gamma  - epsilon);
beta[b_, epsilon_, n2_] := b epsilon^2 n2^(3/2);  


eisl[b_, e0_, g_, gamma_, p_, epsilon_, n2_, x_] := 
            g c[e0] (epsilon)^2 - bindeaa[e0] + 
            e0 ((-2 Log[E^(1/2) x])/x^2 + alpha[gamma, p, epsilon]/x + 
            beta[b, epsilon, n2]/x^(3/2));


eislminx[b_, e0_, g_, gamma_, p_, epsilon_, n2_]:= 
(minxzwischen = FindMinimum[{eisl[b, e0, g, gamma, p, epsilon, n2, x], 0 < x},x];
              minx = x /. minxzwischen[[2]];          
              eisl[b, e0, g, gamma, p, epsilon, n2, minx]);

 Plot[eislminx[10, 1, 0.7, 0.3, 4.9, 0.05, n2], {n2, 0, 10}, 
 PlotPoints -> 2, Evaluated -> True]
```

Mathematica gives the following error messages:

FindMinimum::nrgnum: The gradient is not a vector of real numbers at {x} = {1.}. >>
FindMinimum::nrgnum: The gradient is not a vector of real numbers at {x} = {1.}. >>
FindMinimum::nrgnum: The gradient is not a vector of real numbers at {x} = {1.}. >>
General::stop: Further output of FindMinimum::nrgnum will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
ReplaceAll::reps: {x} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>
ReplaceAll::reps: {x} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>

What is the problem here?

Comment: Your code is not complete so your example cannot be evaluated.  Please correct that, and also format your code using the StackExchange editor.

Comment: I've edited my question and i think it fit's the rules now.

Comment: What is missing in my code? i can process the code as it is and get the plot i expect to get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can find the minimum-producing argument `x` as a function of `n2` using [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NDSolve.html).  We need only find an initial minimum and a differential equation for the trace of the minima.  In fact, we can integrate the minimum value of `eisl` and return a single function that yields the minimum for each `n2`.

Given that the parameters `b,`e0`,`g`,`gamma`,`p`,`epsilon`, are (constant) numbers, the differential equation for the minima may be obtained from

```
Dt[D[eisl[b, e0, g, gamma, p, epsilon, n2, x], x]] == 0 /. x -> x[n2] /. Dt[n2] -> 1
```

If the position `n2`, `x` is at a minimum, then `D[eisl[b, e0, g, gamma, p, epsilon, n2, x]` will be zero. Then as `n2` increases, we want `n2`, `x` to remain at a minimum.  Therefore, partial derivative should not change value but remain at zero.  Therefore, the differential

```
Dt[D[eisl[b, e0, g, gamma, p, epsilon, n2, x], x]]
```

should be zero.  Hence the differential equation above.  This will yield `x` as a function `x[n2]` of `n2`.

To integrate the minimum value of `eisl`, we have `NDSolve` integrate

```
y'[n2] == D[eisl[b, e0, g, gamma, p, epsilon, n2, x[n2]], n2]
```

which can be accomplished at the same time as `NDSolve` integrates `x[n2]`.

There is one difficulty.  For the parameter values in the OP's example, there is no minimum when `n2` is greater that `4.97` or so.  For values of `n2` greater than this, the function `eisl` decreases to a limit `-0.93` as `x -> Infinity`.  I will assume that the limit should be the value of the function.  To handle that exception, I will combine the solution from `NDSolve` with the limit using [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Piecewise.html).

Aside: The real value may be found with the following code.

```
FindRoot[{D[eisl[10, 1, 0.7, 0.3, 4.9, 0.05, n2, x], x] == 0, 
  D[eisl[10, 1, 0.7, 0.3, 4.9, 0.05, n2, x], {x, 2}] == 0}, {x, 
  1}, {n2, 4.9}]
(*
  {x -> 2.97292, n2 -> 4.96976}
*)
```

To get a little closer to the boundary value, I used the option `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"`.

**Code**

Below is a rewritten `eislminx` function.  It returns a pure [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html), so you have to pass it an argument (an input value for `n2`).

```
eislminx[
    b_?NumericQ, e0_?NumericQ, g_?NumericQ, gamma_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ, epsilon_?NumericQ] := 
 eislminx[b, e0, g, gamma, p, epsilon] = (* memoize solution *)
  Module[{y, x, x0, sol, n2},
   x0 = First@
     FindArgMin[{eisl[b, e0, g, gamma, p, epsilon, 0, x], 0 < x}, x];
   sol = NDSolveValue[{
      y'[n2] == D[eisl[b, e0, g, gamma, p, epsilon, n2, x[n2]], n2],
      Dt[D[eisl[b, e0, g, gamma, p, epsilon, n2, x], x]] == 0 /. x -> x[n2] /. Dt[n2] -> 1,
      x[0] == x0, y[0] == eisl[b, e0, g, gamma, p, epsilon, 0, x0]},
     y, {n2, 0, 10}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"];
   With[{
     sol1 = sol,
     lim = Limit[eisl[b, e0, g, gamma, p, epsilon, n2, x],
       x -> Infinity, Assumptions -> n2 > sol["Domain"][[1, 2]]],
     n1 = sol["Domain"][[1, 2]]}, 
    Function[{n}, Piecewise[{{sol1[n], 0 <= n <= n1}}, lim]]
    ]
   ]
```

Example plot:  The first time `eislminx` is called there will be a warning message indicating that `NDSolve` ran into the value of `n2` where there ceases to be a minimum.  Ignore it, or use [`Quiet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Quiet.html).

```
Plot[eislminx[10, 1, 0.7, 0.3, 4.9, 0.05][n2], {n2, 0, 10}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> NDSolveValue::ndsz: At n2$130831 == 4.969743353334403`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The second time you run `Plot`, it will be much faster, because the solution of the differential equation has been saved (for the particular values of the parameters).  See [What does the construct f[x_] := f[x] = ... mean?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/what-does-the-construct-fx-fx-mean).

```
Plot[eislminx[10, 1, 0.7, 0.3, 4.9, 0.05][n2], {n2, 0, 10}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {0.022850, Null}
*)
```

Comment: @11drsnuggles11 You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the updated version of your question, the problem is that there is still some attempt being made inside `Plot` to evaluate the function symbolically, leading to the error messages from `FindMinimum` requiring a numerical starting point, not a symbolic one.

This kind of thing happens a lot, and the most common way to fix it is to define the function only for numerical values of the plot variable. This is done by adding `?NumericQ` to the pattern for the last variable in `eislminx`:

```
ClearAll[eislminx];
eislminx[b_, e0_, g_, gamma_, p_, epsilon_, n2_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{minxzwischen, minx, x},
  (minxzwischen = 
    FindMinimum[{eisl[b, e0, g, gamma, p, epsilon, n2, x], 0 < x}, 
     x];
   minx = x /. minxzwischen[[2]];
   eisl[b, e0, g, gamma, p, epsilon, n2, minx])]

Plot[eislminx[10, 1, 0.7, 0.3, 4.9, 0.05, n2], {n2, 0, 10}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 1, PlotRange -> {-.93, -.82}]
```

[image: plot]

This makes sure that that `eislminx` will not be entered unless the variable `n2` has a numerical value.

In `Plot`, I also replaced the choice of `PlotPoints` (which only provides a starting value for the mesh) by a setting for `MaxRecursion`. Alternatively, when I want more control over the points at which to evaluate the plot function, it's sometimes better to do this:

```
ListLinePlot[
 Table[eislminx[10, 1, 0.7, 0.3, 4.9, 0.05, n2], {n2, 0, 10, .1}], 
 PlotRange -> {-.93, -.82}, DataRange -> {0, 10}]
```

which produces a plot that is indistinguishable from the above, but is based on a `Table` of rigidly defined values.

Comment: Thanks, Jens. But your code isn't speeding up things compared to my last posted code without the function "Evaluate", your's is actually slower. Maybe i expressed myself in an unclear way, i tried to make that code work with the function Evaluate, because this function speeded up the process of the initial, simplified code sample, so i hoped it would do the same with the code at the end of my question. Without evaluate that code at the end of my question works fine, but is slow...but i don't know how to make it work with Evaluate

Comment: I think my code is slower than your (without `Evaluate`) because I replaced `PlotPoints` by `MaxRecursion`. But I can't think of a way to make it faster (even though you could add `Evaluate` to my solution, the speed doesn't change). I thought you wanted to get rid of the error messages, and using `?NumericQ` is the most speed-friendly way I know that does this.

Comment: On my computer, the following is faster in the `Plot` command: `PlotPoints -> 8, MaxRecursion -> 2`

Comment: Yes, i wanted to get rid of the error messages, and thanks again for that, Jens.