# How can I format 256 items into a column of four grids of 16 rows and 8 columns?

Tags: output-formatting, partitions

```
ab = DisplayForm[
  GridBox[Flatten /@ 
    Transpose@
     Partition[
      Table[{n, 
        FactorInteger[n] /. List[p_Integer, 0] :> HoldForm[p] /. 
           List[p_Integer, k_Integer] :> HoldForm[p^k] /. 
          List[x__] :> Times@x /. {} -> 1}, {n, 1, 256}], 16], 
   GridFrame -> True, RowLines -> True, ColumnLines -> True]]
```

result image
[image]

result that I hope
[image]

How to I divide 256 by pieces of four of horizontal 4 * vertical 16?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/notebooks/PrimeNumbers/PrimeFactorization.nb

Comment: You edited your desired result to look different than it did.  You want to print a series of "tables" down the page?

Comment: Yes. I wish result of http://i.stack.imgur.com/qhRGq.png

Comment: Please edit the Answer. I wait for edited Answer.

Comment: Okay.  People on this site answer questions voluntarily on their own time, therefore you should be patient.  I shall revise my answer when I get around to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### New answer

Here is a modularized method.  The first function is from [Trying to write out the prime factorization of a number with CenterDot and Superscript](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60651/121), slightly modified.

```
Format[primeFactorForm[n_Integer]] := 
  Times @@ Superscript @@@ FactorInteger[n] /. _[x_] :> x

block[n_Integer] :=
  Join @@@ Array[{#, primeFactorForm@#} &[# + 16*#2] &, {16, 4}, {64 n - 63, 0}]

grid[m_?MatrixQ] := 
  With[{th = AbsoluteThickness[3]}, Grid[m, Dividers -> ({#, #} &@{th, {True}, th})]]

Array[grid @ block @ # &, 4] // Column
```

[image]

---

### Old answer for original example

There is probably a cleaner way to write this but here's a start for you:

```
tab = Table[{n, 
    FactorInteger[n] /. List[p_Integer, 0] :> HoldForm[p] /. 
       List[p_Integer, k_Integer] :> HoldForm[p^k] /. List[x__] :> Times@x /. {} -> 
      1}, {n, 1, 256}];

eight   = Prepend[Table[True, {7}], AbsoluteThickness[3]];

sixteen = Prepend[Table[True, {15}], AbsoluteThickness[3]];

Grid[Flatten /@ Transpose@Partition[tab, 16], Dividers -> {{eight}, {sixteen}}, 
 ItemSize -> Full]
```

Comment: This looks really fun!

Comment: @ChenStatsYu :-P