# Using an external Pattern breaks Format

Tags: functions, output-formatting, variable-definitions, boxes

I noted while writing [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61211/121) that using an external [`Pattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html) on [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html) doesn't work:

```
p : Format[_foo] := bar

foo[1]
```

> ```
> foo[1]  (* did not work *)
> ```

The `FormatValues` reflect the definition:

```
FormatValues[foo]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[p : _foo] :> bar}
> ```

However the definition is not in the correct form.  Compare the one without `Pattern`:

```
ClearAll[foo];  Format[_foo] := bar;  FormatValues[foo]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[MakeBoxes[_foo, FormatType_]] :> Format[bar, FormatType], 
>  HoldPattern[_foo] :> bar}
> ```

Note that here the rule is rewritten in terms of [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes.html)

```
foo[1]
```

> ```
> bar  (* it works now *)
> ```

Is this behavior a bug or is there a reason for `Pattern` to prevent the standard rule formation?

Comment: Just calling `Format[_foo, _] := bar` gives the message `Format::fttp: Format type _ is not a symbol. >>`

Comment: @ChipHurst Well crud, I copied the wrong code -- *again* -- fix it in a moment.  Thanks.

Comment: Well you had the extra pattern `p : `, so I wasn't sure if you had seen this message before.

Comment: @Chip I was experimenting, trying to better understand this before I posted the question, and I ended up copying the wrong section.  I think now I have the question as intended.