# using memoization with conditional statement

Tags: function-construction, conditional, memoization

I would like some advice about the use of memoization in conjunction with conditional statements. Let me try to explain my problem:

I am constructing a function depending on a number of parameters. Given a set of values I first need to check if they meet certain conditions and then calculate the value of the function like so:

```
myfunction[V_,a_,b_,c_]:=Block[
                          {v1},
                          If[TrueQ[a<b]&&TrueQ[b>c],Abort[]];
                          a*V^2+b*V+c
                          ]
```

The reason why I am constructing the function this way is because I need to study the variation of `myfunction` with `V` for different values of the parameters `a`, `b` and `c` and eventually plot some dependencies. So what I would like to have is to stop the evaluation of the function if the set of parameters `a`, `b` and `c` does not meet the conditions and if they do to plot the variation with `V` (this case is the easy part).

In its current form `myfunction` evaluates without a problem, but is quite slow. Having the `If` evaluated for every value of `V` when plotting the function, is very time consuming, considering that it only needs to be evaluated once.

So I thought I found the solution when I read about memoization. I have tried to rewrite the function like this:

```
myfunction[V_,a_,b_,c_]:=Block[
                          {v1,memo},
                          memo:=memo=If[TrueQ[a<b]&&TrueQ[b>c],Abort[],0.];
                          a*V^2+b*V+c
                          ]
```

But it is not working. The `Abort[]` is never evaluated, only when `TrueQ` is `False` memo becomes 0 and that's all.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Let me know if you need more details.

Update:

Thank you very much for your comments. Following ybeltukov's suggestion I have tried the following:

created a function

```
ExistCond[a_,b_,c_]=Block[
                     {some parameters},
                     definitions;
                     TrueQ[a<b]&&TrueQ[b>c](*main conditions to be satisfied*)
                    ];
```

then use it as follows with `myfunction`:

```
myfunction[V_,a_,b_,c_]/;ExistCond[a,b,c]:=myfunction[V,a,b,c]=Block[
                                                                {extra parameters},
                                                                definitions;
                                                                a*V^2+b*V+c
                                                                ];
```

Unfortunately when I plot `myfunction` it takes a long time first time I evaluate the plot and alas, the second time is very fast. But this is not what I intended. I was expecting that If the conditions in `ExistCond` evaluate to `True` then for the rest of the values of `V`, `ExistCond` is not evaluated again. I have a feeling I am confusing how memoization works.

Comment: `myfunction[V_, a_, b_, c_] /; a < b && b > c := myfunction[V, a, b, c] = a*V^2 + b*V + c;`?

Comment: `/;` is more convenient for conditions. For example, see my [recent answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63436/4678) with conditions and memoization .

Comment: @belisarius or a bit more compact: `mem : myfunction[V_, a_, b_, c_] /; a < b && b > c := mem = a*V^2 + b*V + c;`

Comment: note for this simple example it may not be apparent if a solution has successfully avoided reevaluating the function definition for each `V`.  For testing purpose you might want to use a fuction like `(Pause[10];a V^2+b V+c)`

Comment: Based on your last update, perhaps you need to memoize `ExistCond[]` instead

Comment: for your last example do `Downvalues[myfunction]` after plotting. i expect you will see that you are seperately memorizing the result for each v.

Answer (score 4):

I'd do something like this:

```
myfunction[V_, a_, b_, c_] :=
  Block[{v1},
    If[TrueQ[a < b] && TrueQ[b > c], 
    Abort[],
    (* else *)
    myFunction[v1_, a, b, c] = a*v1^2 + b*v1 + c;
    myFunction[V, a, b, c]
  ]];
```

It is similar to my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/53/how-can-i-implement-dynamic-programming-for-a-function-with-more-than-one-argume/60#60). Basically, you memoize on some of the arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: revision - for this to work properly you need to evaluate the expression inside the function:

```
 myfun[a_,b_,c_]/; a < b && b > c:=
     myfun[a,b,c]=Function[{V}, Evaluate[ function code ] ]
```

usage is then for example:

```
 Plot[myfun[a,b,c][V],{V,0,1}]
```

if you need the `Abort` you can simply do

```
  myfun[a_,b_,c_]:=Abort[]
```

which will naturally catch anything missed by the conditional definition

Specific example:

Suppose we have a function with an expensive part that depends only on some of the parameters:

```
 f[a_, x_] /; a>0  := NIntegrate[ Cos[a  t ]^2 , {t, 0, Pi }]  ( x + a );
 Table[ Table[ f[a, x] , {x, 100}] , {a, 50}] // Timing // First
```

> 82.321728

now memorize the function for each different `a`:

```
 Clear[f];
 f[a_] /; a > 0 := f[a] = Function[{x}, 
    Evaluate[  NIntegrate[ Cos[a  t ]^2 , {t, 0, Pi }]  ( x + a ) ]];
 f[a_] := Abort[];
 Table[ Table[ f[a][ x] , {x, 100}] , {a, 50}] // Timing // First
```

> 0.015600

```
 f[0]
```

> $Abort

@LeonidShifrin's approach of course works as well. Mine is a smidge faster, i suspect because because the `/;` pattern test beats the explicit `If[]`.

Comment: I have tried that, after seeing your and ybeltukov's answer (how do you reference a name?) but it doesn't seem to be what I am looking for (see the updated post!)