# Is there a IsDefinedQ function?

Tags: numerical-integration, function-construction

I have a function which is a bit expensive to calculate. I want to translate and integrate. I want to translate by values on a grid, store the values of the integral and refine the grid. That is, I want to run this:

```
 Table[
 f2[{c, d}] = NIntegrate[f1[{a - c Sqrt[3]/2, b - d}], Element[{a, b}, hex]], 
 {c, 0, 3, 1/2^n}, {d, 0, 3, 1/2^n}]
```

for increasing values of n, but without recalculating previously calculated values, ie don't recalculate f2[{c/2^m,d/2^m}] for m < n.

To do this I'd like to write

```
Table[
If[!IsDefinedQ[f2[{c,d}], f2[{c, d}] = NIntegrate[f1[{a - c Sqrt[3]/2, b -       d}], Element[{a, b}, hex]]], 
{c, 0, 3, 1/2^n}, {d, 0, 3, 1/2^n}]
```

Does a function as IsDefinedQ exist? Do I have a misunderstanding of the what f2[{0,2}] really means in mathematica? Can anybody see a better way to refine such evaluation without reevaluation?

Comment: Search for memoization.

Comment: What is hex? Further, you do not need to have the part `f2[{c, d}] = `in your table. Last, It may be a good idea to give your function (is it f1 or f2?). If it is much too complex, invent a simple one, that shares the main properties with the real one. Then, n should be somehow defined.

Comment: Maybe `ValueQ` will do the trick?

Comment: Note the literal question is not a duplicate.  `ValueQ` does not work because its argument is first evaluated. ( I suspect you need to parse the results of `DownValues` )

Comment: `isDefinedQ[f_, args_] :=
 MemberQ[(First@Cases[#[[1]], f[x__] :> {x}]) & /@ DownValues[f] , 
  args]`  (Obviously you would not use this for the present problem)

Comment: As noted by march you really want [memoization](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/121) but your actual question has also been answered, therefore I marked your question as a duplicate of it instead.