# How would one set up a conditional to evaluate at the last output value (wondrous numbers)

Tags: programming

I know this is pretty fundamental, but I'm trying to learn Mathematica on my own and this is stumping me.

I know 5 is wondrous and it takes 5 steps to reach one, but I can't figure out the input to evaluate at the last output value. Here's what I have:

```
n = 5;
For[n = 5, n <= 20, n++,
 If[EvenQ[n], Print[n/2], Print[3 n + 1]]]
```

I know that n++ will just keep evaluating until n=20, but this is the only thing that gave me an output.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: You will find a lot about your project by searching this site on "collatz" -- the sequences you are generating are often referred to as Collatz sequences.

Answer (score 3):

```
NestWhileList[If[EvenQ[#], #/2, 3 # + 1] &, 5, # != 1 &]

(* {5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Taking advantage of the `4, 2, 1` cycle. (Assuming the conjecture is correct.)

```
step = If[EvenQ@#, #/2, 3 # + 1] &;
step3 = Rest@NestList[step, Last@#, 3] &;
Flatten@FixedPointList[step3, {5}] ~Drop~ -3
(* {5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1} *)
```

This is a needlessly complicated solution intended to highlight some of *Mathematica*'s functionality and syntax.

---

`For` `Reals`: some notes about using a loop ([which you shouldn't use in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica): see `belisarius`'s correct solution) to solve this problem.

First: `n` is the *index* of your sequence of numbers. They just tell you where you are in the sequence. You need to have a variable that represents the value, and you update that variable at every step. So:

```
val = 5;
For[n = 1, n <= 20, n++,
  If[EvenQ[val], val = val/2, val = 3*val + 1]
]
```

will construct the sequence. Unfortunately, it doesn't `Print` out the values, and it doesn't keep the values either. For this, you can do a number of things. For instance,

```
val = 5;
For[n = 1, n <= 8, n++
  , If[EvenQ[val], val = val/2, val = 3*val + 1]; 
  Print[val]
 ]
```

This will print the numbers to the screen. Now, we can do better. Perhaps we want to write the numbers to a list?

```
vals = {5};
For[n = 1, n <= 8, n++, 
   If[EvenQ[Last@vals], AppendTo[vals, Last@vals/2], AppendTo[vals, 3*Last@vals + 1]]]
vals
(* {5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1} *)
```

This is standard sort of programming stuff: building a list by appending values to the list (albeit dynamically, which is not usually where people start when they first start learning programming). However, once again, [this is decidedly *not* the best way to do things in *Mathematica*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica).

We can use recursion and [memoization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/what-does-the-construct-fx-fx-mean/2645#2645):

```
step[n_] := step[n] = If[EvenQ@step[n - 1], step[n - 1]/2, 3 step[n - 1] + 1]
step[1] = 5;
Array[step, 9]
(* {5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1} *)
```

Look up the function `Array` in the documentation.

Alternatively, we can define a function which takes an element of the sequence and spits out the next one:

```
f[x_Integer] := If[EvenQ[x], x/2, 3x + 1]
```

Then, we can `Nest` this function (`Nest` essentially performs function composition `f[f[f[5]]]`):

```
NestList[f, 5, 8]
(* {5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1} *)
```

Alternatively, we can define this as a *pure* function, which is how `belisarius` did it, who is also taking advantage of the fact that we "know" (read: suspect) that this sequence always eventually reaches 1 for any initial input. In that case, he used `NestWhileList` which will go until some condition is met. (`FixedPointList` is a variant of this that will keep calculating until the result doesn't change anymore.)

Comment: Ha! The OP is still struggling with `For` loops :D +1

Comment: @belisarius. I considered posting a working `For` version. Perhaps I should, since perhaps this solution is too snarky.

Comment: In any case, don't post bad code without a BIG warning :)

Comment: @belisarius. You're right. Should be a comment anyway.

Comment: @belisarius. There! I think I salvaged it :)