# Random phases at each run in a wave superposition

Tags: random, version-7

I need to define a function which generates a random real number between 0 and $2\pi$, as a random phase constant for a wave superposition.  **The output should be different each time I re-run the code**, with possibly an optional "fixing" parameter (so the random numbers are kept the same at each re-run of the code).  The wave is defined as a **linear superposition** of functions like this one, where $n$ is an integer :

```
Phi[t_, x_, n_] := Sin[n Pi x] Sin[n Pi t + PhaseCste[n]]
```

The function "**PhaseCste[n]**" is the random phase number which I need.  It should output a different random value for each $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots, \infty$.  Using the following doesn't work :

```
PhaseCste[n] = RandomReal[{0, 2Pi}]
```

because the function "**Phi[t_, x_, n_]**" should be called with the same values of the "**PhaseCste**" in the rest of the code (I'm using the same function "**Phi[t, x, n]**" several times elsewhere in the code).

I hope the question is clear.  Any idea how to achieve this ?

Please, take note that the code should be compatible with ***Mathematica 7.0***.

Comment: I tried this function from another question : **PhaseCste[n] := (SeedRandom[n]; RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}])**.  It is almost working.  The problem is that the values are fixed, i.e. they don't change at each re-run of the code.

Comment: how about `PhaseCste[n_]:=PhaseCste[n]=2Pi RandomReal[]`?

Comment: That last suggestion doesn't work, as stated in my question.  The same **Phi** function is used several times in the code, and should use the same random phase values or else the code outputs only random numbers everywhere (so it gives nothing interesting).

Comment: thats what `PhaseCste[n_]:=PhaseCste[n]` does: it remembers the output for later. If you use the same `n`, you get the same random number. Try this simplified code:  `f[n_]:=f[n]=RandomReal[];   {f/@Range[10] ,f/@Range[10]}`

Comment: This one is almost working (like the semi-solution I gave in my first comment) :  the problem is the output is exactly the same each time I re-run the code.

Comment: try including `Clear[PhaseCste]` at the beginning of your code.

Comment: This is a good step in the right direction !  :-)  it's almost working great !  Strangely, there's a part of my code which don't do what it should, I don't know why yet.  Where should I place the Clear directive ?  At the end ?

Comment: at the very beginning of your code

Comment: That may be it !  8-)  So if I want to fix the output, I just have to comment out that directive, right ?

Comment: What if I want to turn off that Clear directive using a simple parameter, instead of placing it between the comments symbols (\* ... \*) ?  It is a bit tedious to add and remove the (\*...\*) each times.

Comment: Can you see if this works for you? `list = {};
Table[(While[MemberQ[list, r = RandomReal[{2, 2 \[Pi]}]], 
    list = Join[list, {r}];]; r), {i, 1, 1000}];`

Comment: @Algohi Your suggestion is way too complex and "unnatural", compared to the previous solution (which works perfectly).  I just need to polish the **Clear** directive to make the code easier (i.e. simpler) to use.

Comment: How to turn off the **Clear** directive using a simple parameter ?

Comment: @Cham, it is just accumulating the current `RandomReal` in `list` and then generate new one and if it is not in the accumulated `list` then it uses it. It can be used like this: `PhaseCste := (While[MemberQ[list, r = RandomReal[{0, 2 \[Pi]}]], 
   list = Join[list, {r}];]; r)`

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, I think you could write your solution as an answer for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 1):

It seems we managed to find the solution in the comment section, but I was asked to post a self-contained answer for future readers, so here it goes.

The task: to generate random numbers that change from session to session, but are memorised in the current session so that they can be reused.

The solution is easy if we use [memoization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/what-does-the-construct-fx-fx-mean/):

```
PhaseCste[n_]:=PhaseCste[n]=2Pi RandomReal[]
```

This will generate a random number between $(0,2\pi)$ for every `n`, and if we call `PhaseCste` with the same `n` later on, we get the same random number. Example:

First call:

```
PhaseCste /@ Range[5]
{3.72868, 4.78289, 0.948487, 4.66522, 5.74172}
```

Second call:

```
PhaseCste /@ Range[5]
{3.72868, 4.78289, 0.948487, 4.66522, 5.74172}
```

If we close the Mathematica session, the list of numbers will be deleted. If at some point we want to start over *without* closing the session, we can use `Clear`:

```
Clear[PhaseCste]
```

Note that if we do this, we have to define `PhaseCste` again, i.e., we have to execute

```
    PhaseCste[n_]:=PhaseCste[n]=2Pi RandomReal[]
```

again, because by Clearing `PhaseCste`, we delete its "memory" **and** its definition.

Upon a third call:

```
PhaseCste /@ Range[5]
{1.48909, 0.369098, 5.01689, 0.680512, 4.80392}
```

A better approach is to use `DownValues`:

```
DownValues[PhaseCste] = Last@DownValues[PhaseCste];
```

which deletes the "memory" of the function, but **not** its definition.

Upon a fourth call:

```
PhaseCste /@ Range[5]
{3.05886, 2.17051, 1.83634, 2.54535, 4.30857}
```

Finally, in the comment section OP asked an quick/easy way to toggle on and off this deletion process. A simple possibility is to write something like

```
OnOff=False;
If[OnOff,Clear[PhaseCste]]
PhaseCste[n_]:=PhaseCste[n]=2Pi RandomReal[]
```

By changing `False` to `True`, the DownValues of `PhaseCste` will get automatically deleted.