# How to initialize downvalues from a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, downvalues

The `For` expression below initializes downvalues of a variable `a` from the values in a list `list`:

```
Module[
 {   a
   , list = {3, 1, 4}
 }
 , For[i = 1, i <= Length[list], i++, a[i] = list[[i]]]
 ; a[3]
]
(* 4 *)
```

---

Is there a simpler way to implement such an assignment?  In particular, I'm looking for a way that does not explicitly iterate over the list.

---

The naive attempt below fails, but at least shows the sort of expression I'm hoping to find:

```
Module[
 {   a
   , list = {3, 1, 4}
 }
 , Array[a, Length[list]] = list
 ; a[3]
]
(* a$941099[3] *)
```

Comment: I think the term you are looking for is `DownValues` instead of "Array". The `Array` function just creates lists and is in no way connected to something like `someArrayName[someIndex]`

Comment: in mathematica an array is a sub-type of a list.  Essentially a list that is not ragged. http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayQ.html

Comment: note while there may be some reason to do this, in general if you have a list-like thing you should actually use a list.  If you use downvalues to hold your list you give up all the rich functionality of mathematica list operations.

Comment: I second george's opinion on staying away from "indexed variables" i.e. DownValues. You loose all that higher-order-function-goodness e.g. `Map`, `Fold` and `Select`. If you really need some kind of readily available "index" additional to your data have a look at `Association`

Comment: I remember reading, a long, long, long time ago (probably in the very first "*Mathematica* book"), that in *Mathematica*, expressions of the form `a[i]` (single brackets!) were used to represent subscripted variables, as found in standard mathematical notation, i.e. $a_i$.  Maybe this is no longer "good *Mathematica*", but I think it was "the official line" at some point.

Comment: @kjo you are right that expressions of the form `a[i]` are commonly used that way (since using the real `Subscript` with any kind of assignment except maybe UpValues is evil).

Comment: Thanks everyone for pointing out my misconceptions about "arrays" in *Mathematica*.  I've reworded my post to get rid of the nonsense (I hope).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Set` has the `HoldFirst` attribute. You need to use `Evaluate` if you want to do this the way you suggest in your question:

```
Module[{array, list = {3, 1, 4}},
 Evaluate[Array[array, Length[list]]] = list;
 {array[1], array[2], array[3]}
 ]
(* Out: {3, 1, 4} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly you want to transform a list e.g. `{a,b,c,d}` into `DownValues` of a Symbol with some name e.g. `array1`. Sometimes this is called an *indexed variable* (although I think this term is misleading). The following function does just that:

```
toDownvalues[name_, list_] := MapIndexed[(name[First@#2] = #1) &, list]

ClearAll@array1
toDownvalues[array1, {a, b, c, d}]

Table[array1[i], {i, 1, 4}]
(* {a, b, c, d} *)
```

Comment: Or use `array1 /@ Range[4]` instead of the `Table` construct.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon, the `Table` is just there to show that indeed we attached the entries from the list to the Symbol `array1` via DownValues. I though that using `Table` is maybe clearer to the OP because it explicitly uses an index.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a solution that doesn't iterate over a list, you may be interested by what is called ["memoization"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2639/5467). The target of memoization is not to assign DownValues to a symbol as you ask. Memoization is a optimization for speed. Assignment of Dowvalues to a symbol is a "side effect" (in all meanings of the term), which is not recommended, but here, that may correspond to your need.

The idea of Memoization is that your array is built more and more each time you call `array[index]` whith a new index :

Here is the intialisation :

```
list = {3, 1, 4, 8};
array[i_] := (array[i] = list[[i]])

Definition[array]
```

[image]

The array definition is no more than `array[i]=list[i]`. This is a parasitic term that may annoy you, depending of your application.

Then if you call `array[index]` with say, index=1, then the DownValue 3 is added to the definiton of array (`array[1]=3`) :

```
array[1]
Definition[array]
```

[image]

and so on ...

```
array[2]
Definition[array]
```

[image]

Of course, if you want to load the entire array in one time at the beginning, you need to do something similar to a iteration, for example :

```
array /@ Range[Length[list]]
Definition[array]
```

[image]