# Replace elements of array

Tags: list-manipulation

I have an array of elements and want to assign each element a specific value from a vector, at the same time I need the function ni[i] for the ith element of the list. I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
Clear[nn, ni, m];
pop = {191202, 29234};
m = 2;
nn = Array[ni, m];
ni[i_] := pop[[i]]
ni[i]

During evaluation of In[834]:= Part::pkspec1: The expression i cannot
be used as a part specification. >>

Out[839]= {191202, 29234}[[i]]
```

Comment: With this definition, ni[1] and ni[2] are properly defined. But you can't use i because it doesn't have any value in the Part command [[ ]].

Comment: Look at the solutions proposed in [How to initialize downvalues from a list?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/117692/27951), which appears to be an exact duplicate of your question; consider also that doing this will prevent you from using the rich machinery available in *Mathematica* to deal with lists natively, so it may not be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will work for you.

```
Clear[nn, ni, m];
pop = {191202, 29234};
m = 2;
nn = Array[ni, m]
```

> `{ni[1], ni[2]}`

```
Do[ni[i] = pop[[i]], {i, Length[pop]}];
nn
```

> `{191202, 29234}`