# Speeding iterative computation

Tags: performance-tuning, programming

I want to get the following iterative sequence

```
x[0] = 0.9;
T[x_] := Piecewise[{{1 - x, 0 <= x < 1/7}, {(x + 6)/7, 
     1/7 <= x <= 1}}];
a[n_] := n/(n + 5)^5;
b[n_] := (2 n/7 n + 5)^(1/2);
x[n_] := (1 - a[n - 1])* T[x[n - 1]] + 
   a[n - 1]*T[(1 - b[n - 1]) *x[n - 1] + b[n - 1] T[x[n - 1]]];
For[n = 1, n < 50, n++, Print[x[n]]];
```

But it is taking to much time to execute. In 10 to 15 hours, it reached to the 18 iteration and the required value is still not received, which is 1. I think to reach 1, 20 to 30 iteration must be required.

Is there any other way to reach the answer "1" sooner?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use the formatting guide (click `{}` while typing up your question). As a first suggestion, if you're using loops, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Your code is highly inefficient.  For instance, what do you mean by `(2 n/7 n + 5)`?  Is this merely `5 + 2/7 = 37/7`?  Likewise, do you need the second conditional in your `Piecewise`?  And why define all your functions, e.g., `a`, when you can merely compute that in `x`?  And by all means replace `For` with `Table` and eliminate `Print`.

Comment: @David G. Stork, (2 n/7 n + 5)is actually 2n/(7n+5). Different function is due to n, if n change, the valve of a, b and then x will be changed with each iteration.

Comment: @Ben Kalziqi, Other then loop, any option?

Comment: Follow @DavidG.Stork 's advice and use `Table`, or maybe `Map`. The timing on this function is terrible; moreover, why are you convinced that this even converges to 1 after a finite iterations?

Comment: 1 is the fixed point of the function T, and the iterative procedures is the convergence procedure and since it is proved that the procedure is convergent to fixed point

Comment: um.... `2 n/7 n +5` is `2 n^2 / 7 +5` .. @marwat use some parenthesis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **memoization**. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) for a description of the memoization in general, and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2639/27951) for its *Mathematica* implementation. This will avoid having to recalculate all the previous values to determine the next one:

```
Clear[x, T, a, b]
T[x_] := T[x] = Piecewise[{{1 - x, 0 <= x < 1/7}, {(x + 6)/7, 1/7 <= x <= 1}}]
a[n_] := a[n] = n/(n + 5)^5
b[n_] := b[n] = (2 n/7 n + 5)^(1/2)

x[0] = 0.9;
x[n_] := x[n] = (1 - a[n - 1])*T[x[n - 1]] + 
                  a[n - 1]*T[(1 - b[n - 1])*x[n - 1] + b[n - 1] T[x[n - 1]]]

Table[{i, x[i]}, {i, 0, 50}]

(* Out: {{0, 0.9}, {1, 0.985714}, {2, 0.997831}, {3, 0.999571}, 
         {4, 0.999847}, {5, 0.99991}, {6, 0.999937}, {7, 0.999954}, 
         {8, 0.999965}, {9, 0.999973}, {10, 0.999979}, {11, 0.999984}, {12, 0.999987}, 
         {13, 0.99999}, {14, 0.999992}, {15, 0.999993}, {16, 0.999994}, {17, 0.999995}, 
         {18, 0.999996}, {19, 0.999997}, {20, 0.999997}, {21, 0.999998}, 
         {22, 0.999998}, {23, 0.999998}, {24, 0.999998}, {25, 0.999999}, {26, 0.999999}, 
         {27, 0.999999}, {28, 0.999999}, {29, 0.999999}, {30, 0.999999}, {31, 0.999999}, 
         {32, 0.999999}, {33, 0.999999}, {34, 1.}, {35, 1.}, {36, 1.}, {37, 1.}, {38, 1.}, 
         {39, 1.}, {40, 1.}, {41, 1.}, {42, 1.}, {43, 1.}, {44, 1.}, {45, 1.}, {46, 1.}, 
         {47, 1.}, {48, 1.}, {49, 1.}, {50, 1.}}
*)
```

Also, avoid loops (`For`, `Do`), but rather use vector constructs (e.g. `Table`, `Map`). The `Table` above now calculates almost instantaneously.

---

If you are interested in how far from exactly $1$ the value of $x(i)$ is for a certainly value of $i$, then you may resort to arbitrary precision calculations, after changing the precision of your starting point `x[0]`. For instance, using 20-digit precision calculations:

```
x[0] = 0.9`20;

DiscretePlot[
 Round@Log10[Abs[x[i] - 1]], {i, 0, 50},
 Frame -> True, LabelStyle -> {Black, 14},
 FrameLabel -> {"iteration number", "Log(error)"}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks a lot @MarcoB. It works very very beautifully

Comment: Sir Is the value of 1 is exact?

Comment: @Marwat It is indistinguishable from $1$ at the precision at which the claculation was carried out, which happens to be machine precision because you specified `0.9` as a starting point. If you want exact results, use `x[0] = 9/10`; if you want higher precision numerical results, say e.g. to 20 digits of precision, then use ``x[0] = 0.9`20``.

Comment: @Marwat See also the addition to my answer above

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I understand. I think 1. is not exact but 1 is exact. Now Sir please tell me about the plotting of graph. Let us call the about function [x_n], the M function. And let us suppose there is one another function say K function, for example K function is x[n_] := (1 - a[n - 1])* T[x[n - 1]] + 
   a[n - 1]*T[(1 - b[n - 1]) *x[n - 1] + b[n - 1] T[x[n - 1]]]. Now we need to draw the graphs of both M and K function to compare the convergence. Please help.....

Comment: @Marwat Since this second part of your problem is not really related to your original question, it would be best for you to start a new, different question on this site, rather than continuing the discussion in comments. "Moving target" questions are discouraged.

Comment: okey Sir thanks a lot for so much cooperation

Comment: What is meant by  Log(error) by definition?

Comment: @Marwat I'm not using that rigorously. I just mean to show the order of magnitude of the difference between the value of the recursion after a certain number of iterations and $1$, the convergence value. So a value of -6 indicates that the value of the recursion after a certain number of steps is only $10^{-6}$ units away from $1$. It's not properly an *error*, but I'd didn't have a better name for it at the time.

Comment: @Marco_B thanks for explanation. So what can be the better name for it?

Comment: @Marwat "Log (distance from convergence)" perhaps?

Comment: @Marwat You are very welcome. If you think that my answer appropriately addressed your problem, you could consider formally accepting it by clicking on the grey check mark next to it.

Comment: What you mean by "you could consider formally accepting it by clicking on the grey check mark next to it"? it is not clear to me?