# How to implement recursive function

Tags: recursion, integer-sequence

I'm trying to do the following (taken from an answer by *Watson* to [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922904/examples-of-self-referential-sequences?noredirect=1#comment3949206_1922904) on Math SE):

> Start with $x_1=2$, say. Then define $$x_{n+1} = |\{i \in \{1,\dots,n-1\} \;:\; x_i=x_n\}|$$ i.e. number of times you see $x_n$ in $\{x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}\}$.
>   For instance, you get: $$2,0,0,1,0,2,1,1,2,2,3,0,3,1,…$$

**How can this sequence be programmed?**

I tried the following:

```
f[1]=2;
f[2]=0;
f[n_] := Count[Table[f[k - 1], {k, 2, n - 2}], f[n - 1]]
```

I also tried to use `RecurrenceTable`, but I couldn't find away around just putting $n$ `RecurrenceTable`s inside the function, which kinda defeats the purpose.

Any help would be much appreciated!

*Edit:* With the new code (thanks to corey), I get

```
In = Table[f[n], {n, 1, 10}]
Out = {2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0}
```

which isn't *quite* right.

Comment: In the `Table`, iterator `k` starts from 1, i.e. the first element of the table is `f[1-1]=f[0]` which is undefined. Second, I think the upper limit wasn't supposed to be `k-1` if you're iterating over `k`.

Comment: I have some trouble with obtaining $x_2$; shouldn't it be always zero, because that's the number of $x_1$ seen in an empty set? At least MMA gives `Table[x[i],{i,1,0}]` to be `{}`. Please clarify.

Comment: @corey979 Yes, it should always be zero. And I guess (w.r.t. the first comment), then the upper should probably be $n-2$ - I'll change it.

Comment: OK: `f[n_] := Count[Table[f[k - 1], {k, 2, n - 1}], f[n - 1]]` (i.e., `n-2` changed to `n-1`); now `Table[f[i], {i, 1, 14}]` gives `{2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 3, 1}`.

Comment: @corey979 Great, please make it answer!

Comment: @corey979 It is an extremely calculation-heavy operation, huh? Any ideas for making it more optimal? (And I of course meant "make it **an** answer" in the previous comment.)

Comment: A non-recurrent version, hopefully faster. `f[n0_Integer?NonNegative, n_Integer?Positive] := Module[{counter, last = n0}, counter[_] = 0; Do[last = counter[last]++, n - 1]; last]`

Comment: Please see [this link on recursive functions](https://www.wolfram.com/wolfram-u/an-elementary-introduction-to-the-wolfram-language/27-applying-functions-repeatedly.en.html) It is pretty much straightforward. Regards,
EDS

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
f[1] = 2;
```

To compute $x_{n+1}$ you want to check how many $x_n$'s are in the set $\{x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}\}$, i.e. for `f[n]` you want to generate a `Table` of `{f[1],...,f[n-2]}`:

```
Table[f[k], {k, 1, n - 2}]
```

and count how many `f[n-1]`'s are there:

```
f[n_] := Count[Table[f[k], {k, 1, n - 2}], f[n - 1]]
```

Alternatively, you can shift the index by 1 (which doesn't affect the output of `Table`):

```
f[n_] := Count[Table[f[k - 1], {k, 2, n - 1}], f[n - 1]]
```

In either case,

```
Table[f[i], {i, 1, 14}]
```

> {2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 3, 1}

---

**EDIT:** It indeed takes in the case of $n=30$ an amount of time too long to wait for the output. This can be solved with the standard construct

```
f[n_]:=f[n]=...
```

Then,

```
Table[f[i], {i, 1, 1000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.267906, Null}

Up to $n=200$:

[image]

---

**EDIT:** [An interesting animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8cdR.jpg) of the above (credit to [Lovsovs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922904/examples-of-self-referential-sequences?noredirect=1#comment3950122_1923753)).

Interesting behaviour of this rule:

[image]

Comment: I don't think the second line is necessary.

Comment: Huh; it appears that indeed after the correction `f[2]` doesn't have to be defined.

Comment: I'm trying to animate f(n) for different starting values, but I don't know how to include multiple lines as the expr in `Animate[]`: `Animate[{
  m = 1000;
  f[1] = k;
  f[n_] := f[n] = Count[Table[f[k - 1], {k, 2, n - 1}], f[n - 1]]
     Table[f[n], {n, 1, m}];
  ListPlot[Table[f[n], {n, 1, m}]]},
 {k, 1, 10}]` is what I am trying to do. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

## Recursive Function

Let's start with simple recursive function [provided by @corey979](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126154/14303):

```
ClearAll[fRecursive]
fRecursive[1] = 2;
fRecursive[n_] := fRecursive[n] =
    Count[Table[fRecursive[k], {k, 1, n-2}], fRecursive[n - 1]]
```

It works as expected:

```
Array[fRecursive, 15]
(* {2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 3, 1, 3} *)
```

but it's a bit slow:

```
Table[fRecursive[i], {i, 10^4}] // MaxMemoryUsed // AbsoluteTiming
(* {23.9591, 2043888} *)
```

---

## Non-recursive Function

### General

To write faster version, let's think what knowledge, about previous elements, do we need, in order to calculate next element.

In `fRecursive`, in each `n`-th step, we create list of all elements up to `n-2` (since [memoization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2639/14303) is used we don't recalculate them) and count number of occurrences of `n-1` element in that list. If  `n-1` element is in the list it means that in some previous step we already had to calculate number of its occurrences in a sub-list of currently used list, so if we would carry information about previous counts, between iterations, we could possibly speedup calculations.

As a "counter" we need a mapping from non-negative integers, representing elements of sequence, we want to generate, to non-negative integers representing number of occurrences of those elements in sequence generated so far. Since elements of sequence are counts of some elements in already generated sequence, they can't be greater than total number of sequence elements, that we want to generate (except first element which can be arbitrary large), thus our mapping can be implemented as an array of integers with length equal to maximal index of element we want to generate.

Initially there are no elements in sequence, so we start with "counter" array of zeros. In each step we take "current" element of sequence, since it appears in sequence, we increment value of "counter" associated with current element, and take result as new "current" element for next iteration. Our expected sequence is list of consecutive "current" values.

Above algorithm is implemented in following function, which gives elements with indices from `min` to `max` from sequence starting with `n0` value:

```
ClearAll[fGeneral]
fGeneral = Compile[{{n0, _Integer}, {min, _Integer}, {max, _Integer}},
    Module[{current = -1, counter = Table[0, {max + 2}]},
        counter[[1]] = n0;
        Do[current = counter[[current + 2]]++, {min - 1}];
        Table[current = counter[[current + 2]]++, {max - min + 1}]
    ],
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", CompilationTarget -> "C"
];
```

We get expected results:

```
fGeneral[2, 1, 15]
(* {2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 3, 1, 3} *)
fGeneral[2, 10, 15]
(* {2, 3, 0, 3, 1, 3} *)
```

same as with recursive function:

```
fGeneral[2, 1, 10^3] === Array[fRecursive, 10^3]
(* True *)
```

but much faster and using much less memory:

```
fGeneral[2, 1, 10^4] // MaxMemoryUsed // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.00008, 320560} *)
```

Note that since our `counter` can handle at most `max` values, above function will give an error if `n0` value is greater than `max`.
We'll deal with this special case later.

### Looking for a Pattern

Now to find more optimizations let's look at table of values of our sequence as in [answer of @m_goldberg](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126208/14303) and [answer of @ubpdqn](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126235/14303).

```
Table[
    Module[{max = 100, list, n0SecondPos, n0PlusOnePos},
        list = fGeneral[n0, 1, max];
        n0SecondPos = Position[list, n0, {1}, 2][[2, 1]];
        n0PlusOnePos = 
            Replace[Position[list, n0 + 1, {1}, 1], {{{i_}} :> i, {} -> max + 1}];
        Join[
            Take[list, 1],
            Style[#, Red] & /@ Take[list, {2, n0SecondPos}],
            Take[list, {n0SecondPos + 1, n0PlusOnePos - 1}],
            Style[#, Blue] & /@ Take[list, {n0PlusOnePos, -1}]
        ]
    ],
    {n0, 0, 10}
] // TableForm
```

[image: Table of sequence values]
(click on image to enlarge it)

#### Small Elements

We can see that up to second occurrence of first sequence element, there are always consecutive integers, starting from zero, interlaced with zeros  (red elements).

So elements up to `2 n0 + 2` can be generated using following function, taking advantage of fast, built-in vectorized operations:

```
ClearAll[fSmall]
fSmall = Function[{n0, min, max},
    Module[{result = Quotient[Range[min - 2, max - 2], 2]},
        result[[(2 - Mod[min, 2]) ;; ;; 2]] = 0;
        If[min === 1, result[[1]] = n0];
        result
    ]
];
```

We get expected results:

```
fSmall[2, 1, 2 2 + 2]
(* {2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2} *)
```

same as with `fGeneral` function:

```
fSmall[2, 1, 2 2 + 2] === fGeneral[2, 1, 2 2 + 2]
(* True *)
fSmall[10^7, 1, 2 10^7 + 2] === fGeneral[10^7, 1, 2 10^7 + 2]
(* True *)
```

but faster and using less memory:

```
fSmall[10^7, 1, 2 10^7 + 2] // MaxMemoryUsed // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.269374, 320001984} *)
fGeneral[10^7, 1, 2 10^7 + 2] // MaxMemoryUsed // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.424444, 640000640} *)
```

We' ll use `fSmall` for generating "relatively small" sequences i.e. those with `max <= 2 n0 + 2`.
Note that this will automatically take care of special cases for which `fGeneral` doesn't work, i.e. those with `max < n0`

#### Large Elements

Second relevant observation is generalization of [discovery made by @Watson](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1923753) and [@m_goldberg](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126208/14303). Starting from first occurrence of `n0+1` value, we can see a simple pattern (blue elements).

Dependence of position of first `n0+1` value on `n0` can be found by *Mathematica*:

```
Table[Position[fGeneral[n0, 1, 10^3], n0 + 1, {1}, 1][[1, 1]], {n0, 30}] //
    FindSequenceFunction
(* 3 + 2 #1 + #1^2 & *)
```

For elements starting from `n0^2 + 2 n0 + 3` we can see pattern described by m_goldberg and Watson.

```
partitionedTable = Module[{min = #^2 + 2 # + 3, k = 2 # + 2},
    Partition[fGeneral[#, min, min + 10 k], k] // TableForm
] &;

partitionedTable@2
```

> $\begin{array}{cccccc}
>  3 & 0 & 3 & 1 & 3 & 2 \\
>  4 & 0 & 4 & 1 & 4 & 2 \\
>  5 & 0 & 5 & 1 & 5 & 2 \\
>  6 & 0 & 6 & 1 & 6 & 2 \\
>  7 & 0 & 7 & 1 & 7 & 2 \\
>  8 & 0 & 8 & 1 & 8 & 2 \\
>  9 & 0 & 9 & 1 & 9 & 2 \\
>  10 & 0 & 10 & 1 & 10 & 2 \\
>  11 & 0 & 11 & 1 & 11 & 2 \\
>  12 & 0 & 12 & 1 & 12 & 2 \\
> \end{array}$

```
partitionedTable@5
```

> $\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
>  6 & 0 & 6 & 1 & 6 & 2 & 6 & 3 & 6 & 4 & 6 & 5 \\
>  7 & 0 & 7 & 1 & 7 & 2 & 7 & 3 & 7 & 4 & 7 & 5 \\
>  8 & 0 & 8 & 1 & 8 & 2 & 8 & 3 & 8 & 4 & 8 & 5 \\
>  9 & 0 & 9 & 1 & 9 & 2 & 9 & 3 & 9 & 4 & 9 & 5 \\
>  10 & 0 & 10 & 1 & 10 & 2 & 10 & 3 & 10 & 4 & 10 & 5 \\
>  11 & 0 & 11 & 1 & 11 & 2 & 11 & 3 & 11 & 4 & 11 & 5 \\
>  12 & 0 & 12 & 1 & 12 & 2 & 12 & 3 & 12 & 4 & 12 & 5 \\
>  13 & 0 & 13 & 1 & 13 & 2 & 13 & 3 & 13 & 4 & 13 & 5 \\
>  14 & 0 & 14 & 1 & 14 & 2 & 14 & 3 & 14 & 4 & 14 & 5 \\
>  15 & 0 & 15 & 1 & 15 & 2 & 15 & 3 & 15 & 4 & 15 & 5 \\
> \end{array}$

```
partitionedTable@9
```

> $\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccc}
>  10 & 0 & 10 & 1 & 10 & 2 & 10 & 3 & 10 & 4 & 10 & 5 & 10 & 6 & 10 & 7 & 10 & 8 & 10 & 9 \\
>  11 & 0 & 11 & 1 & 11 & 2 & 11 & 3 & 11 & 4 & 11 & 5 & 11 & 6 & 11 & 7 & 11 & 8 & 11 & 9 \\
>  12 & 0 & 12 & 1 & 12 & 2 & 12 & 3 & 12 & 4 & 12 & 5 & 12 & 6 & 12 & 7 & 12 & 8 & 12 & 9 \\
>  13 & 0 & 13 & 1 & 13 & 2 & 13 & 3 & 13 & 4 & 13 & 5 & 13 & 6 & 13 & 7 & 13 & 8 & 13 & 9 \\
>  14 & 0 & 14 & 1 & 14 & 2 & 14 & 3 & 14 & 4 & 14 & 5 & 14 & 6 & 14 & 7 & 14 & 8 & 14 & 9 \\
>  15 & 0 & 15 & 1 & 15 & 2 & 15 & 3 & 15 & 4 & 15 & 5 & 15 & 6 & 15 & 7 & 15 & 8 & 15 & 9 \\
>  16 & 0 & 16 & 1 & 16 & 2 & 16 & 3 & 16 & 4 & 16 & 5 & 16 & 6 & 16 & 7 & 16 & 8 & 16 & 9 \\
>  17 & 0 & 17 & 1 & 17 & 2 & 17 & 3 & 17 & 4 & 17 & 5 & 17 & 6 & 17 & 7 & 17 & 8 & 17 & 9 \\
>  18 & 0 & 18 & 1 & 18 & 2 & 18 & 3 & 18 & 4 & 18 & 5 & 18 & 6 & 18 & 7 & 18 & 8 & 18 & 9 \\
>  19 & 0 & 19 & 1 & 19 & 2 & 19 & 3 & 19 & 4 & 19 & 5 & 19 & 6 & 19 & 7 & 19 & 8 & 19 & 9 \\
> \end{array}$

Lists with elements following above pattern can be generated using following function:

```
ClearAll[fLarge]
fLarge = Compile[{{n0, _Integer}, {min, _Integer}, {max, _Integer}},
    Module[{shift = n0^2 + 2 n0 + 3},
        Table[
            If[EvenQ[i],
                Quotient[i, 2 n0 + 2] + n0 + 1
            (* else *),
                Quotient[Mod[i, 2 n0 + 2] - 1, 2]
            ],
            {i, min - shift, max - shift}
        ]
    ],
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", CompilationTarget -> "C"
];
```

It gives expected results:

```
fLarge[2, 2^2 + 2 2 + 3, 15]
(* {3, 0, 3, 1, 3} *)
```

same as with `fGeneral` function:

```
fLarge[2, 2^2 + 2 2 + 3, 10^7] === fGeneral[2, 2^2 + 2 2 + 3, 10^7]
(* True *)
fLarge[10^2, 10^4 + 2 10^2 + 3, 10^7] === fGeneral[10^2, 10^4 + 2 10^2 + 3, 10^7]
(* True *)
```

generation of large lists is slower than with `fGeneral`:

```
fLarge[2, 2^2 + 2 2 + 3, 10^7] // MaxMemoryUsed // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.556881, 240000192} *)
fGeneral[2, 2^2 + 2 2 + 3, 10^7] // MaxMemoryUsed // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.11998, 320000320} *)
```

but algorithm used in `fLarge`, in contrast to `fGeneral`, doesn't need to generate all previous elements so it's much faster when we need to generate sequence of elements with relatively high `min` index.

For example generation of only one element is much faster and uses almost no memory:

```
fLarge[2, 10^7, 10^7] // MaxMemoryUsed // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.000016, 352} *)
fGeneral[2, 10^7, 10^7] // MaxMemoryUsed // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.059807, 80000480} *)
```

Empirically `fLarge` becomes faster, more or less, when `min > 9/10 max` (at least at my computer):

```
fLarge[2, 9 10^6, 10^7] // MaxMemoryUsed // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.056439, 24000472} *)
fGeneral[2, 9 10^6, 10^7] // MaxMemoryUsed // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.05865, 104000600} *)
```

### Final Function

Putting all three functions together we get:

```
ClearAll[fInternal]
fInternal = Function[{n0, min, max},
    Which[
        max <= 2 n0 + 2,
            fSmall[n0, min, max],
        9 max < 10 min && min >= n0^2 + 2 n0 + 3,
            fLarge[n0, min, max],
        True,
            fGeneral[n0, min, max]
    ]
];
```

Our final function with basic tests on argument patterns:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[n0_Integer?NonNegative, {min_Integer?Positive, max_Integer?Positive}] /; min <= max := fInternal[n0, min, max]
f[n0_Integer?NonNegative, max_Integer?Positive] := fInternal[n0, 1, max]
f[n0_Integer?NonNegative, {n_Integer?Positive}] := First@fInternal[n0, n, n]
```

First argument of `f` function is first element of sequence, second argument is standard sequence specification, so `{n}` will give `n`-th element of sequence, `{min, max}` will give list containing elements from `min` to `max`, `max` will give elements from 1 to `max`.

```
f[2, 15]
(* {2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 3, 1, 3} *)
f[2, {9, 15}]
(* {2, 2, 3, 0, 3, 1, 3} *)
f[2, {15}]
(* 3 *)
```

Comment: Very nice, this solution made it easier to animate the `ListPlot` of the sequence!

Answer (score 8):

There are already two answers but I think it still might be interesting to reconsider the problem.

My idea is to write a generator `s[n]` for the sequence `{f[1], f[2], ..., f[n]}` and then, should we need `f`, to we could always define it as

```
f[n_Integer?Positive] := s[n][[-1]]
```

The generator is pretty simple when expressed as a recursive function.

```
s[1] = {2}; s[2] = {2, 0};
s[n_] := s[n] = 
  Module[{prev = s[n - 1]}, prev~Join~{Count[s[n - 2], prev[[-1]]]}]
```

Then

```
s[14]
```

> `{2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 3, 1}`

and

```
ListPlot[s[200], AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: plot]

The regularity of plot suggests that there is a simple non-recursive solution. We should look into that.

Evaluating `s[40]` gives

> ```
> {2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
>  3, 0, 3, 1, 3, 2, 
>  4, 0, 4, 1, 4, 2, 
>  5, 0, 5, 1, 5, 2, 
>  6, 0, 6, 1, 6, 2, 
>  7, 0, 7, 1, 7, 2}
> ```

After ten somewhat irregular integers, the sequence settles down into blocks of six of the form `..., k, 0, k, 1, k, 3, k + 1, 0, k + 1, 1, k + 1, 2, ...`. This can be coded as

```
Clear[f]
MapThread[
  Set[f[#1], #2] &, {Range[10], {2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2}}];
f[n_Integer /; n > 10] :=
   Module[{q, r},
     {q, r} = QuotientRemainder[n - 11, 6];
     Switch[r,
       0 | 2 | 4, 3 + q,
       1 | 3 | 5, (r - 1)/2]]
```

As a test:

```
Table[f[i], {i, 40}]
```

which, of course, gives the same result as `s[40]`.

This version of `f` is very fast.

```
AbsoluteTiming[Do[f[i], {i, 10000}]]
```

> `{0.112455, Null}`

P.S. Perhaps this is an example of what Stephen Wolfram calls [Computational Thinking](http://blog.wolfram.com/2016/09/07/how-to-teach-computational-thinking/). That is, rather than doing math to get the result, I just messed around with Mathematica.

Answer (score 3):

```
f[a_, 0] := a
f[a_, n_] := 
 Nest[Append[#, Count[#[[1 ;; -2]], #[[-1]]]] &, {a, 0}, n - 1]
```

e.g.

```
Framed@TableForm[{Row[Riffle[f[#, 15], "  "]], 
     RepeatedTiming[f[#, 15]][[1]]} & /@ Range[9], 
  TableHeadings -> {None, {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(a\), \(n\)]\): 0\
≤n≤15", "Repeated\nTiming"}}]
```

[image]