# Partitioning a number into consecutive integers

Tags: equation-solving, partitions, integer-sequence, diophantine-equations

Consider `n=45`; then

$$1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9=45$$
$$5+6+7+8+9+10=45$$
$$7+8+9+10+11=45$$
$$14+15+16=45$$
$$22+23=45$$

**Question:** how to find all representations of a given positive integer `n` as a sum of *consecutive* positive integers smaller than `n` with an efficient *Mathematica* implementation? A brute-force method is straightforward, but it's likely to fail for big `n`, so a more clever idea is required.

It is sufficient (and concise) to provide only the start and end values of each sequence, i.e. `{1, 9}`, `{5, 10}` etc.

Comment: Why the close vote? This is a question about how to efficiently implement any algorithm in MMA.

Comment: Reason to close:  There is nothing in the question that relates directly to the *Mathematica* computer language; the "representation" of a sequence of consecutive integers as the first and last integer is of course trivial and unworthy of a question; very closely related questions are posted on *mathematics.stackexchange.com* e.g., http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611135/consecutive-partitions-of-positive-integers (showing this question belongs on that site).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I disagree. In my answer I showed 3 different implementations with different efficiencies. I find this question similar to [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126150/how-to-implement-recursive-function), which arose to a simple mistake, but lead to great answers exploiting MMA abilities. About the question here, I found it surprising that `Solve` works so well. Finally, it gained votes and obtained also two other answers, what I take as an indicator that this Q&A is not off topic. I'm not arguing, just presenting my motivation and opinion, to be clear.

Comment: See also [this oldie from Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/59131/11619)

Comment: corey979:  I urge you in the future to link any question posted here specifically to *Mathematica*.  As Jyrki and I have pointed out, the question as it stands is unrelated to *Mathematica*, even though your self-answer is.

Comment: Related: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47115/consecutive-numbers-sum-of-a-number

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I took it as a challenge to avoid using `Solve`, which can be slower than a direct assault. If $a$ is the first number in the sum of consecutive positive integers, and $k$ is the count of integers summing to $n$, then $n=k*a+k(k-1)/2$. Solve this for $a=n/k-(k-1)/2$, with bounds $1 \le k \le {\rm Floor}[(\sqrt{8n+1}-1)/2]$. Consider the odd and even divisors of $n$ and $2n$, respectively, to give the following. This includes the $k=1$ case of the sum of one number, just $n$.

```
CoreyPartition[n_] :=
   Block[{bound = Floor[(Sqrt[1 + 8 n] - 1)/2], oddk, evenk, k, e},
      oddk = Pick[#,OddQ[#]] &[Pick[#, UnitStep[bound - #], 1]&[Divisors[n]]];
      evenk = Pick[#, UnitStep[bound - #], 1] &[Divisors[2 n]];
      e = IntegerExponent[n, 2];
      evenk = Pick[evenk, IntegerExponent[evenk, 2], 1 + e];
      k = Reverse[Sort[Join[oddk, evenk]]];
      Transpose[{n/k - (k - 1)/2, n/k + (k - 1)/2}]]
```

A slight modification to `f[n]` for cases with no solution, such as $n=1,2,4,8,\ldots$.

```
f[n_] := If[# == {}, {}, {a, b} /. #]&[
            Solve[(a + b) (b - a + 1)/2 == n && 0 < a < n && 0 < b < n, 
                  {a, b}, Integers]]
```

The two solutions agree, for example:

```
Sum[Total[Most[CoreyPartition[n]] - f[n]], {n, 1, 200}]
```

However, testing with large integers such as `n=10^40` showed `CoreyPartition[n]` was over 200 times faster.

**Update**

Given `DivisorPairs` from Mr.Wizard:

```
DivisorPairs[n_] := 
   Thread[{#, Reverse[#]}][[ ;; Ceiling[Length[#]/2]]] &[Divisors[n]]
```

there is the following one-liner which is twice as fast as `CoreyPartition`.

```
CoreyFastPartition[n_] :=
   Reverse[Pick[#, Total[Mod[#, 4], {2}], 2]] &[ DivisorPairs[8 n]] /.
      {r_Integer, s_Integer} -> {(s - r + 2)/4, (s + r - 2)/4}
```

This code returns the trivial solution {n,n}, which may be removed with `Most`.

Answer (score 23):

The sum of consecutive numbers from $a$ to $b$ is

$$\frac{(a+b)(b-a+1)}{2}$$

hence simply

```
f[n_] := {a, b} /. 
 Solve[(a + b) (b - a + 1)/2 == n && 0 < a < n && 0 < b < n, {a, b}, Integers]

f[45] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.019466, {{1, 9}, {5, 10}, {7, 11}, {14, 16}, {22, 23}}}

It is straightforward and rather fast. As a test case:

```
f[4500] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.063403, {{23, 97}, {27, 98}, {78, 122}, {93, 132}, {168, 
>      192}, {176, 199}, {293, 307}, {496, 504}, {559, 566}, {898, 
>      902}, {1499, 1501}}}

This distribution is interesting:

```
ListPlot[tab = Table[{i, Length @ f[i]}, {i, 1000}], Filling -> Axis, 
   Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
   FrameLabel -> {"n", "Length@f[n]"}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {12.3098, Null}

[image]

The biggest number of partitions (`Length@f[n] == 15`) for `n <= 1000` is for `n = 945`:

```
Select[tab, #[[2]] == Max @ tab[[All,2]] &]
```

> {{945, 15}}

while `Length@f[944] == 1` and `Length@f[946] == 3`.

It works also with **huge** numbers:

```
f[10^11] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.149738, {{60688, 451312}, {925363, 1027762}, {1240938, 
>      1319062}, {4872573, 4893052}, {6392188, 6407812}, {24412015, 
>      24416110}, {31998438, 32001562}, {159999688, 
>      160000312}, {799999938, 800000062}, {3999999988, 
>      4000000012}, {19999999998, 20000000002}}}

```
f[10^40] // AbsoluteTiming // Short
```

> {1.55024,{{39445166261547851563,146819348661547851562},<<38>>,{<<1>>}}}

*(I'm surprised it works so well, and I think that the timing is quite acceptable too.)*

---

A sample rejection method (brute force, with just a little trick to use `Ceiling[n/2]`):

```
n = 45;
MinMax /@ 
 First /@ Select[
   Flatten[#, 1] & @
    Table[{Range[i, j], Total @ Range[i, j]}, {j, 1, Ceiling[n/2]}, {i, 1, j}],
      #[[2]] == n &]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.000803, Null}

works well for this simple case (however, on my laptop it needs **14 sec** for `n = 4000`) , but when

```
n = 4500;
```

it crashes the kernel.

---

Additionally,

```
g[n_] := Cases[FrobeniusSolve[Range @ n, n], {0 ..., 1 .., 0 ..}, Infinity]
```

is very slow:

```
(o = g[45]); // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {43.871, Null}

although works:

```
MinMax /@ (Pick[Range@45, #, 1] & /@ o) // Sort
```

> {{1, 9}, {5, 10}, {7, 11}, {14, 16}, {22, 23}}

Answer (score 7):

```
d[n_] := With[{dv = Divisors[n]}, {#, n/#} & /@ 
   Pick[dv, # < Sqrt[n] & /@ dv]]
f[a_, b_] := With[{p = a - 1, q = b}, {(q - p)/2, (p + q)/2}]
res[n_] := Rest@Cases[f @@@ d[2 n], {_Integer, _Integer}]
```

So,

```
ListPlot[{#, Length[res[#]]} & /@ Range[1000], Filling -> Axis]
ListPlot[DeleteCases[{#, #2 - #1 + 1 & @@ (res[#][[-1]])} & /@ 
   Range[1000], {_, {}}], Filling -> Axis, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Point[{# (# + 1)/2, #} & /@ Range[45]]}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Maximum Length of run"]
Cases[{#, res@#} & /@ Range[5000], {x_, {}} :> x]
```

[image]

Powers of 2 no non-trivial representation.
Triangular numbers shown as red points.