# Speeding up computation of a sequence

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, compile

I am simulating the dynamics of a spring mass system impact an obstacle. I will not go into the details of the numerical scheme, but here are the general parameters and functions:

```
n = 10;
m = 1/n*IdentityMatrix[n];
k = n*SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] == 1 -> -1, {i_, i_} /; 
        i != n -> 2, {n, n} -> 1}, {n, n}] // Normal;
c = 0.02*k;
F0 = 10;
e = 1;
d = 1;
T = 3.4;
h = 0.002;
theta = .5;
mhat = m + h*theta*c + h^2*theta^2*k;
mhatinv = Inverse[mhat];
Fext[i_] := {F0*Cos[2 Pi/T*h*i]}~Join~ConstantArray[0, n - 1];
prox[x_, b_] := Piecewise[{{-b, x < d}, {Min[0, -b], x >= d}}]
```

Then I define the following 3 sequences:

```
Clear[ulist, vlist, vfree];

ulist[0] = ConstantArray[0, n];
vlist[0] = ConstantArray[0, n];
vfree[0] = vlist[0];

vfree[i_] := vlist[i - 1] + mhatinv.(-h*c.vlist[i - 1] - h*k.ulist[i - 1] - 
     h^2*theta*k.vlist[i - 1] + h*(theta*Fext[i] + (1 - theta)*Fext[i - 1]))
ulist[i_] := ulist[i - 1] + h*(theta*vlist[i] + (1 - theta)*vlist[i - 1])
vlist[i_] := vfree[i][[;; -2]]~Join~{-e*vlist[i - 1][[-1]] + (1 + e)*
     prox[ulist[i - 1][[n]], -vfree[i][[n]]]}
```

Then it is possible to simulate the time-evolution of the mechanical system, and plot e.g. the trajectory of the contacting mass:

```
Table[ulist[i] = ulist[i]; vfree[i] = vfree[i]; vlist[i] = vlist[i], {i, 3000}];
Show[
   ListPlot[Table[{i*h, ulist[i][[n]]}, {i, 3000}]], 
   Plot[1, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
   AxesLabel -> {"Time", "Position"}]
```

[image]

It works pretty well, however I am pretty sure this code can be improved a lot in terms of computational efficiency. I am thinking of using `Compile`, but it is not clear to me what to include (e.g., should the functions `prox` and `Fext` be defined in `Compile`? Should `Compile` be called for each iteration, or should the iteration process be included in it?).

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I would start by memoizing these functions:

```
mem : vfree[i_] := mem =
  vlist[i - 1] + 
   mhatinv.(-h*c.vlist[i - 1] - h*k.ulist[i - 1] - h^2*theta*k.vlist[i - 1] + 
      h*(theta*Fext[i] + (1 - theta)*Fext[i - 1]))

mem : ulist[i_] := mem =
  ulist[i - 1] + h*(theta*vlist[i] + (1 - theta)*vlist[i - 1])

mem : vlist[i_] := mem =
  vfree[i][[;; -2]]~
   Join~{-e*vlist[i - 1][[-1]] + (1 + e)*prox[ulist[i - 1][[n]], -vfree[i][[n]]]}
```

Then eliminate this code as it becomes redundant:

```
Table[ulist[i] = ulist[i]; vfree[i] = vfree[i]; vlist[i] = vlist[i], {i, 30000}];
```

For me this takes total plotting time from 4.5 seconds down to 0.4 second.

Comment: What is the function of `mem` here? Is it just a shorthand for repeating the function name in `f[x_] := f[x] = rhs`?

Comment: @aardvark2012 Yes, just personal convention; see the bottom of [(2676)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2676/121) for my reasoning.

Comment: Nice. I read the nice post you mention in the comment above, but don't understand why it is so much faster than when saving `f[x]=f[x]` afterwards. Could you please elaborate a bit on that? Also, do you think it could be still possible to increase the speed significantly?

Comment: @anderstood (1) I think because only values used are computed.  I didn't check to see if that was equivalent in this case, and looking now I see that the plot is only to 3,000 rather than the 30,000 used in the Table.  That by itself would account for the timings I observed.  In some cases though the *order* of computation is important. (2) I hope so.  As I said *I would start by ...* but I didn't have time to look for other optimizations.  I did note that the output of `ulist` and `vlist` are already packed arrays which is one sign of optimized code.