# Strange behaviour of ValueQ inside loops

Tags: evaluation, variable-definitions

**TL;DR:** I have a series of variables $x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots$ which to which I assign values inside a loop. However, when I use `ValueQ` to determine which values I've already assigned, the results don't appear to make much sense.

**Minimal example:** 
Code:

```
Clear[x];
For[i = 1, i < 4, i = i + 1,
x[i] = i;
Print[i, ": ", ValueQ[x[i]], " ", ValueQ [x[i + 1]], " ", ValueQ [x[i + 10]] , " ", ValueQ[x[2]]]]
```

Output:

```
1: True True True False
2: True True True True
3: True True True True
```

Explanation: In $i$-th iteration of the loop, I assign the value to `x[i]`. Hence, in $i$-th iteration the values `x[1], x[2], ..., x[i]` are defined, but `x[i+1], x[i+2], ...` are not. However, when I try to check if `x[j]` are defined, Mathematica tells me that: 
1) `x[i]` is defined, as expected; 2) `x[i+1]` is defined, although it is not yet defined; 3) `x[i+10]` is defined, although it is never defined at all; 4) `x[2]` is defined if and only if $i \geq 2$, as expected.

**Motivation:** In the application I have in mind, I'm computing values $x_i$ in a somewhat haphazard order. It so happens that to compute $x_i$ it is useful to know $x_j$ where $j$ is a function of $i$ (a non-trivial one). At the time $x_i$ is computed, I would like to check if $x_j$ has already been computed, and use its value if it has (if it has not, then I need to compute $x_i$ in a more time-consuming way). However, when I try to implement this using `ValueQ`, I get the unexpected behaviour described above.

**Question:** How does this behaviour arise, and how can I change the above code to make it work?

Comment: "ValueQ gives False only if expr would not change if it were to be entered as Wolfram Language input. " - `x[i + 10]` **would** change, becoming `x[10+i]`

Comment: For your application here, use a smarter test function, like `IntegerQ` or `NumericQ`

Comment: @JasonB Actually, it would change also because `i` has a value within the loop.

Comment: From my experience, lists work much faster than constructions like x[i]. And they have no such weird artifacts.

Comment: @Szabolcs even if it had no value, it still would change, `ValueQ[f[symbolWithoutValue + 10]]` returns `True`

Comment: @JasonB. Yes, I didn't contest that. I mentioned it to make it clear that exchanging the order wouldn't fix it.

Comment: You can test in this manner: `With[{index = i + 1}, ValueQ[x[index]]]`

Comment: Sounds like you should be using [memoization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html)?

Comment: Your TL;DR is not really a TL;DR, because it doesn’t stand on its own.  It’s just an introduction to what follows in the post.

Answer (score 4):

since `x[1+1]` evaluates (at least) to `x[2]`, `ValueQ` returns `True` as it is already different than the input.

You don't have to check if you already calculated `x` for e.g. `2`. [You can use memoization:](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2639/5478)

```
  x[n_]:=x[n] = ...
```

So once e.g. `x[5]` is called, each subsequent `x[5]` will not require recomputation.

Comment: Thank you for explaining where the issue comes from. However, in this particular case, momoization is not the solution: I specifically need to check if x[i] (say) is defined, and do one of two different things depending on the outcome (i.e. if I learn that I could speed up computing x[1] by knowing the value of x[101] but I haven't yet computed x[101], I *don't* want to compute x[101] but rather I want to run a completely different routine).

Comment: @JakubKonieczny I see, without details I can only suggest to check `MatchQ[x[i], _x]`.

Comment: @JakubKonieczny or `ValueQ[x[#]]&[1+1]`