# What is wrong with the Mann iteration?

Tags: iterators

I have written the Mann iteration's code for the mapping $\frac{z}{1+z^2}$, in Mathematica, but it is very slow. In fact it needs more than 200 seconds for obtaining 17th iteration, while Matlab does 100 iterations of the the Mann iteration in a second.
Would you please tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
Clear[x, z, n, lambda, f]
For[n = 1; x[1] := 1;
lambda := 1/2; f[z_] := z/(1 + z^2), n < 21, n++,
x[n_] := (1 - lambda) x[n - 1] + lambda f[x[n - 1]]; Print[Timing[N[x[n]]]]]
```

Comment: Do you really want to use exact arithmetic all the way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following approach might be more "standard Mathematica":

```
Clear[f]
f[z_] := z/(1 + z^2)

lambda = 0.5;

Clear[x]
x[1] = 1;
x[n_] := x[n] = (1 - lambda) x[n - 1] + lambda f[x[n - 1]]

list = Table[x[n], {n, 1, 150}];
ListPlot[list, PlotRange -> All]
```

[Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) (i.e. saving intermediate values of `x[n]`, see also [Q2639](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2639/27951)) appears to help considerably. Execution is then practically instantaneous even for large $n$.

It also helps greatly to get away from symbolic calculations: instead of `lambda = 1/2`, use the machine-precision value `lambda = 0.5`.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

More in general, you might also want to take a look at:

- [Why should I avoid the For loop in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/27951)
- If you do want to use loops (e.g. `Do`) that return `Null`, then take a look at [Collecting expressions during evaluation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CollectingExpressionsDuringEvaluation.html)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and complete answer

Comment: @morapi You are welcome.

Comment: Do you mean `f[z_] := f[z] = z/(1 + z^2)` (`z` instead of `x`)?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Actually that part does not benefit from memoization. I took out the `f[x]` altogether, which must have been a leftover from a previous draft. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

note it is a little faster to march it out directly without recursion:

```
 list = NestList[ (1 - lambda) # + lambda f[#] & , 1 , 149]
```

Comment: It is. Thank you