# Slow processing of coupled differential equation using NDsolve

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
AA[x_, y_, t_] := Sqrt[3 + 2*Cos[(t*x)/E^(t^2/2)] + Cos[2*y] + 2*Cos[(t*y)/E^(t^2/2)]]

Dx[x_, y_,t_] := (Cos[2*(3/E^9 + t/E^t^2 + x)] + 2*Cos[3*(3/E^9 + t/E^t^2) + x]*Cos[y] + (2*I)*Cos[y]*Sin[2*(x + (3/E^9 + t/E^t^2)*x)])/ Sqrt[1 + Abs[Cos[2*(3*(3/E^9 + t/E^t^2) + x)]]]
F[t_] :=  E^-t^2 (1 - 2 t^2)
Rx[x_, y_, t_] := Dx[x, y, t] E^(-I Integrate[AA[x, y, r], {r, -3, t}])

L[x_, y_, t_] := -I F[t] Rx[x, y, t]
M[x_, y_, t_] := -I F[t] Conjugate[Rx[x, y, t]]

eqn[x_, y_, t_] := {A1'[t] == L[x, y, t] A2[t],
                    A2'[t] == A1[t] M[x, y, t],
                    A1[-3] == 0, A2[-3] == 1}
sol := {A1, A2} /. (NDSolve[eqn[x, y, t],{A1, A2}, {t, -3, 3}])
P=Table[sol, {x, 1, 2}, {y, 1, 2}]
```

I am having a problem getting a solution. It just keeps running. And, considering the fact I need it for a wide range of `x` and `y`, I definitely need some help.

Comment: Try to construct a *minimal* example. Are you sure it's NDSolve that takes long? I think it's `Integrate`. Have you tried running parts of your code individually (which should always be the first debugging step you take)?

Comment: `NDSolve` has a hard time to solve a differential equation with symbolic parameters `x` and `y`. Have a look into `ParametricNDSolve` which, of course, includes reading its documentation.

Comment: Try e.g. `Rx[1, 2, t]`, and notice that the integral is not solved.

Comment: I suggest rephrasing the problem so that it does not include an integral. This is often possible by introducing an additional function to solve for in `NDSolve`, representing the integral (differentiating it by `t` just gives the integrand).

Comment: thanks szabolcs, as you said the problem comes from the integral in Rx. Is there any way I can get past it?

Comment: thanks henrik I will go through that too

Comment: Use `NIntegrate` like this: `Rx[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := 
 Dx[x, y, t] E^(-I NIntegrate[AA[x, y, r], {r, -3, t}])`

Comment: Using a slightly higher order integration rule saves a couple of seconds: `NIntegrate[AA[x, y, r], {r, -3, t}, Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 11}]`

Comment: thanks michael i will try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `NDSolve` to compute the indefinite integral saves a lot time, when the integral will be evaluated many times as in this appliction:

```
ClearAll[int];
mem : int[x_, y_] := (* mem represents the function call and "memoizes" the result *)
  mem = Block[{i, r, t}, 
    NDSolveValue[{i'[r] == AA[x, y, r], i[-3] == 0}, i, {r, -3, 3}, 
     PrecisionGoal -> 12,  (* integrand is nice: squeeze out a bit more precision *)
     InterpolationOrder -> All]];  (* ensure accuracy between interpolation nodes *)
Rx[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := 
  Dx[x, y, t] E^(-I int[x, y][t]);
```

This brings the execution time down to around 0.15 sec.  (Simply replacing `Integrate` with `NIntegrate` brought the time down to around 7 sec.)

Here is an explanation of memoization: [What does the construct f[x_] := f[x] = ... mean?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/what-does-the-construct-fx-fx-mean/2676#2676)

Comment: Thanks Michael, I will give it a go the way you said.

Comment: @maeinss You're welcome.  I think Szabolcs' idea is a bit better, but I don't know if he will have time to answer.

Comment: that was amazing I never thought it that way. However, even with the value of Rx the solution still keeps running. I am taking about last few steps. eqn[x_, y_, t_] := {A1'[t] == L[x, y, t] A2[t],A2'[t] == A1[t] M[x, y, t],A1[-3] == 0, A2[-3] == 1}
sol := {A1, A2} /. (NDSolve[eqn[x, y, t],{A1, A2}, {t, -3, 3}])
P=Table[sol, {x, 1, 2}, {y, 1, 2}]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one interpretation of [Szabolcs's idea](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193032/slow-processing-of-coupled-differential-equation-using-ndsolve#comment502522_193032), using the variable `i[t]` for the integral:

```
ClearAll[Rx, eqn];
Rx[x_, y_, t_] := Dx[x, y, t] E^(-I i[t]);  (* i[t] is the integral up to t *)

eqn[x_, y_, t_] = {A1'[t] == L[x, y, t] A2[t], 
   A2'[t] == A1[t] M[x, y, t], A1[-3] == 0, A2[-3] == 1, 
   i'[t] == AA[x, y, t], i[-3] == 0};  (* the last two eqns define the integral *)

PrintTemporary@Dynamic@{x, y, Clock[Infinity]};
sol := {A1, A2} /. (NDSolve[eqn[x, y, t], {A1, A2}, {t, -3, 3}])
P = Table[sol, {x, 1, 2}, {y, 1, 2}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

It takes around `0.03` sec., significantly faster than my (other) answer.

Comment: It seems to work. I surely need to work on the details of the code. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Hi Michael, I was analyzing the code and I have one confusion. How do you specify i[-3]=0? Integral of AA[x, y, t] at t=-3 can have any value. If so, how can we evaluate.

Comment: @maeinss I specified `i[-3]` with the code `i[-3] == 0`; that's ***how*** I did it. Perhaps you're asking ***why***? `i[t]` represents `Integrate[AA[x, y, r], {r, -3, t}]`. For `t == -3`, the integral is zero, no matter what the value of `AA[x, y, t]`, since the end points of integration are both `r == -3`.. Or are you asking something else entirely?

Comment: Sorry, I stated it wrong, I meant why. I can't see a reason why integration of AA[x,y,r/t] should be 0 at the boundary. A1[-3] == 0, A2[-3] == 1 because they are probabilities. However, even at those endpoint values system can have finite AA value other than 0 and so its integration can be non-zero. (In my case AA is the Energy.)

Comment: @maeinss It's basic calculus: $\int_{-3}^{-3} f(r)\;dr = 0$ by definition, no matter what $f(r)$ is (provided $f$ is defined at $-3$). Whether $f(-3) = 10$ or $f(-3) = -100$, the integral is zero.  Compare by executing `Integrate[AA[x, y, r], {r, -3, -3}]` in *Mathematica*.

Comment: Thanks Michael, you have been a great help. It makes sense.