# Problem in NDSolve (Mathematica 7)

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

Following a piece of program

```
v0 = 100.; a = 1.;   
pot[x_] := If[Abs[x] <= a, -v0*(1 - Abs[x]/a), 0];
sol1[e_] = NDSolve[{sy1''[x] + sy1[x]*(e - pot[x]) == 0, sy1[0] == 1, sy1'[0] == 0}, {sy1}, {x, -a, 0}];
u1[x_, e_] := sy1[x] /. sol1[e];
pu1[x_, e_] = Evaluate[D[u1[x, e], x]]
Plot[pu1[x,-1.2],{x,0,-1}]
```

gives errors like:

`NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x == 0..`

`ReplaceAll::reps: {NDSolve[.......]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.`

Please help.

Comment: @Bill, I want to do as a function of e.

Comment: @Bill. Oh! I want sol1 as function e , then u1 as function of x and e. I cant use paraNDsolve, because of lower version of mathematica

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037) to [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037) for the use of `_?NumericQ`.

A second issue is the dependence of a function on a global variable.  This is particularly easy to overlook when the variable, such as `x` in `sol1[]`, is not treated as a programming variable but as an inert symbol.  However, `Plot[.., {x,..}]` sets the value of the global variable `x` when evaluating the function to be plotted.  When `sol1[]` is called via `pu1[x, -1.2]` inside `Plot`, the symbol `x` will have been given a numeric value and `NDSolve` will fail.  So it's often important to localize such variables.  This can be done via `Module[{x},..]` or `Block[{x},..]`.  `Module[]` creates new unique symbols; `Block[]` temporarily clears any values of a global symbol.  In the little bit of code where it is used, it makes little difference which you choose.  If you're feeling overprotective, then localizing the global symbol `sy1` might be good.  But that would have consequences, since other functions (e.g. `u1`/`pu1`) use `sy1` and would require them to be rewritten.

For the sake of efficiency, I mimicked the functionality of `ParametricNDSolveValue`, which stores the last `NDSolve[]` solution and reuses it unless the values of the parameters change (just `e` in this case).  To prevent an excessive use of memory, when the parameters change values, the old saved solution is cleared (`Unset[]`).  The line `sol1[e] = First@res` stores the solution, which will be used when `sol1[e]` is called until the value of `e` changes; see [What does the construct f[x_] := f[x] = ... mean?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/what-does-the-construct-fx-fx-mean).

```
ClearAll[pot, sol1, u1, pu1, sy1];
v0 = 100.; a = 1.;
pot[x_] := If[Abs[x] <= a, -v0*(1 - Abs[x]/a), 0];
sol1[e_?NumericQ] := Block[{x},
   Quiet@Unset[sol1[#]] &@sol1["last"];  (* Unset last e *)
   With[{res = NDSolve[{sy1''[x] + sy1[x]*(e - pot[x]) == 0, sy1[0] == 1, 
        sy1'[0] == 0}, {sy1}, {x, -a, 0}]},
    (sol1["last"] = e;   (* remember last e so that it can be Unset *)
      sol1[e] = First@res) /; ListQ[res] (* NDSolve succeeds => res is a List *)
    ]
   ];
u1[x_, e_?NumericQ] := sy1[x] /. sol1[e];
pu1[x_, e_?NumericQ] := sy1'[x] /. sol1[e];

Plot[pu1[x, -1.3], {x, 0, -1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How about using `ParametricNDSolveValue`:

```
v0 = 100.; a = 1.;
pot[x_] := If[Abs[x] <= a, -v0*(1 - Abs[x]/a), 0];
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{sy1''[x] + sy1[x]*(e - pot[x]) == 0, 
    sy1[0] == 1, sy1'[0] == 0}, sy1, {x, -a, 0}, e];
fun = pfun[-1.2];
Plot[Evaluate[D[fun[x], x]], {x, 0, -1}]
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that I do not have higher version of Mathematica supporting the ParaNDsolve, that is why I am using NDSolve

Comment: Why don't you add to the question what version you have?

Comment: @Thank you, Added

Answer (score 2):

Here is another method that might work that retains essentially the same code you show in your question (unfortunately I do not have WM7 so I can't check if it will work for you).

```
f[ee_] := Module[{e = ee, v0 = 100., a = 1.},
  pot[x_] := If[Abs[x] <= a, -v0*(1 - Abs[x]/a), 0];
  sol1 = NDSolve[{y''[x] + y[x]*(e - pot[x]) == 0, y[0] == 1, 
     y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, -a, 0}];
  u1[x_] = y[x] /. sol1;
  pu1[x_, e_] = Evaluate[D[u1[x, e], x]];
  Plot[pu1[x, e], {x, 0, -1}]
  ]
Manipulate[f[e], {e, -2, 2}]
```

You will note that I've used the Manipulate function at the end just so you can confirm interactively whether this indeed works. Hope this helps!