# NDSolve for non-analytical forms

Tags: differential-equations

I came across a problem of coupled differential equations of a non-analytical results. It follows that `NDsolve` requires an evaluated form of equations to be fed into it for a differential equation to process.But, my functions can't be evaluated analytically. I want to know if there is any possible way to tackle the problem. I have created a sample problem here:

First I create a Complex system just to confirm I will get non-analytical solutions:

```
Mat[n_, x_, y_] := SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}, {n, n}] -> {x^3, x I + 5 y^2 + 4, Sqrt[x]},
                   Band[{1, 2}, {n, n}] -> {y^3, Sqrt[x + I x^3 - y^2 + 4], 
                   Sqrt[x - y^2]}, Band[{3, 1}, {n, n}] -> {I x^3, x + y x^2 + 4, Sqrt[x + y^2]}}]

eval[n_, x_, y_] := Eigensystem[Mat[n, x, y]][[1]]

evec[n_, x_, y_] := Eigensystem[Mat[n, x, y]][[2]]
```

Secondly, I will form some time-dependent functions so as to cover the complexity of my problem:

```
val = D[Mat[8, x, y], x];
x2[x1_, t_] := x1 + t^2
y2[y1_, t_] := y1 + t
T1[x1_, y1_] := {I Conjugate[#], #} &@(Conjugate[evec[8, x1, y1][[6]]].SparseArray[
                ArrayRules[val] /. {x -> x1, y -> y1}, Dimensions[val]].evec[8, x1, y1][[7]] // N)
T2[t_] := {t, t^2}
T3[x1_, y1_, t_] := T1[x2[x1, t], y2[y1, t]]
T4[x1_, y1_, t_] := Re[eval[8, x2[x1, t], y2[x1, t]][[7]]] - Re[eval[8, x2[x1, t], y2[x1, t]][[8]]]//N
```

Last, I will list them in the required form of equation and initial conditons for processing:

```
t0=-5;
eqns[x1_, y1_, t_] := {A1'[t] == (T2[t].T3[x1, y1, t]) A2[t], A2'[t] == A1[t] (T2[t].Conjugate[T3[x1, y1, t]]),
                      i'[t] == T4[x1, y1, t],A1[t0] == 0, A2[t0] == 1, i[t0] == 0}
sol1 = ParametricNDSolve[eqns[x1, y1, t], {A1[t], A2[t]}, {t, t0, 5}, {x1, y1}]
```

As you see, say, `eqns[x1, y1, t]` can't be evaluated unless you provide numerical values of all the parameters. How do we solve the equations in that case. I would be grateful for your help.

(Note: this is a sample just to reflect my problem, feel free to make reasonable changes)

Comment: `eqns` also has a function `i`. Have you defined it or should it be solved for?

Comment: It’s a way of writing if there is an integral in your calculations . I want to evaluate integral of ‘T4’ alongside. So, Yes, ‘i’ should be solved for. I have provided initial conditions for it.

Comment: I am really not sure what you are trying to do here. Can you simplify your example to something much simpler? Are you looking for the `NumericQ` functionality, as described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/27951)?

Comment: Sure, Let's just solve for a parameter containing `T4`. Much more simplified, how can i solve this: `ParametricNDSolve[ i'[t] == T4[x1, y1, t], i[t0] == 0, {i[t]}, {t, t0, 5}, {x1, y1}]`.

Comment: @MarcoB All I am trying is to solve a differential equation using NDsolve. The equations can only be numerically determined. Above, In the comment I have presented simplified version of it. Please do mention if you want any  further info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your equations are of the form `x' = f(x), x = {x1,...,xn}`, flow part `f(x)` can be defined implicitly, i.e. as a black box outside of `NDSolve`.

This explicit form:

```
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t]==-y[t]-x[t]^2,y'[t]==2x[t]-y[t]^3,x[0]==y[0]==1},{x,y},{t,20}]
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t],y[t]}/.sol],{t,0,20}]
```

can be converted to:

```
ClearAll[flow] ;
flow[x_,y_] := flow[x,y] = {-y-x^2,2 x-y^3} ;

ClearAll[fx,fy] ;
fx[arg__?NumericQ] := flow[arg][[1]] ;
fy[arg__?NumericQ] := flow[arg][[2]] ;

sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == fx[x[t],y[t]] ,y'[t]==fy[x[t],y[t]],x[0]==y[0]==1},{x,y},{t,20}] ;
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t],y[t]}/.sol],{t,0,20}]
```

### Edit

In your case:

```
ClearAll[flow] ;
flow[x1_, y1_, t_,A1_,A2_,i_] :=  flow[x1,y1,t,A1,A2,i] = {
    (T2[t].T3[x1, y1, t]) A2,
    A1 (T2[t].Conjugate[T3[x1, y1, t]]),
    T4[x1, y1, t]
} ;

ClearAll[f1,f2,f3] ;
f1[arg__?NumericQ] := flow[arg][[1]] ;
f2[arg__?NumericQ] := flow[arg][[2]] ;
f3[arg__?NumericQ] := flow[arg][[3]] ;

t0=-5;
(* return only i *)
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {
        A1'[t] == f1[x1,y1,t,A1[t],A2[t],i[t]],
        A2'[t] == f2[x1,y1,t,A1[t],A2[t],i[t]],
        i'[t] == f3[x1,y1,t,A1[t],A2[t],i[t]],
        A1[t0] == 0, A2[t0] == 1, i[t0] == 0
    },
    i,
    {t, t0, 5},
    {x1, y1}
] 
sol[1,1]
```

Comment: Thank you. When you defined `flow[x,y] = {-y-x^2,2 x-y^3}` that still becomes an analytical representation. Whereas, if you see in mine it has a set delayed. Could you just possibly obtain `ParametricNDSolve[ i'[t] == T4[x1, y1, t], i[t0] == 0, {i[t]}, {t, t0, 5}, {x1, y1}]` from my example.

Comment: @Rupesh, you can define `flow[x_,y_] := flow[x,y] = whatever`, `flow[x_,y_] := flow[x,y]` part is a kind of [memorization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/what-does-the-construct-fx-fx-mean), since both `fx` and `fy` evaluate `flow` with the same argument

Comment: I understand what you are saying but since there are many intermediary steps from defining a flow to NDSolve in my case, how do you go on about it. Plus, I am trying to find a time evolution of a separate function but not `x` an `y` itself. I am afraid that I can't make a resemblance between your suggestion and my problem. I would be glad if you could take my own example and at least find an evolution for `i[t]`. You can change the time intervals or I expect the solution parametric in terms of x and y

Comment: @Rupesh, see the edit.

Comment: @ I.M I want to thank you a lot and appreciate your time and patience. I was totally unaware of this approach and now it does make sense to me. I tried fitting your first example to my case and messed up, it was bad on my part. Sorry if I behaved impolitely.

Comment: @Rupesh, np, glad to help

Comment: Hi I.M I am reaching you out because my actual problem still isn't solved. I tried all the available methods but the `NDSolve` just gets stuck. I have tried the regular approach and the one you suggested. I would be really grateful if you could look into my problem when you have time. Here is the link to the [notebook](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjWzOvwBhDPGmH_PAyR20_5iF4hV?e=hacnqX)

Comment: @Rupesh, rewriting of equations seems to [work](https://ibb.co/pfzdn1D)

Comment: Thank you for your help. On the side note the indexing way which I wrote earlier works too, maybe `Through` is the key.Here is a [pic](https://ibb.co/hHjrQHx) of using `A1[1,t]` and `A11`.Another thing, the runtime is almost 10 mins which I feel is very huge considering the computation involved, did you have a similar experience?. Thank you again for your help

Comment: @Rupesh, indeed, this indexing does work, still, it is confusing. Might be so for NDSolve[] too, because your eqs look like pdes. Tested in wolframclould, took less than 1m to compute for one fixed value of `qx`. I've changed indexing and added memorization `sorted[n_,kx_]:=sorted[n,kx] = ...`. `Through` should not effect performance here.

Comment: Thanks again. It's an ODE in time which does contain some parametric partial derivatives. I agree for a two-variable scenario indexing isn't required but If we set Range to different, then you will have multiple variables and different sets of initial conditions. see [fig](https://ibb.co/4NZNysg). For 1 set of initial condition `initials[[1]]`,  our ODE will look as [pic](https://ibb.co/3cTj8LW). For this, it's stuck. Would you feel free to try it for a higher range scenario in your cloud computation? .Modified [file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjWzOvwBhDPG9CHr8oKn8oXOQJUC?e=1VSBld).

Comment: @Rupesh, it takes about 2s per evaluation with basic wolframcloud plan, you can try to adjust the integration method or optimize the computation of functions involved, [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g1chryhs2pbu5sp/submission_.nb?dl=0).

Comment: You are amazing and really good at scripting. I will go through it and hopefully it will be solved. One final request, would you remove the dropbox link as it's my project file. Also, I will cite you if I get anything publishable, I'll let you know. Thank you so much for your help.