# How to efficiently store the result of a function

Tags: functions

Consider the following code:

```
f[x_]:= SomeCodeAbout[x]
g[x_]:= f[x]
```

It links `g` with `f`, namely when `g` is called, `f` runs, and so will `SomeCodeAbout[x]`. However, if I want just to store the **result** of `f[x]`, which could be some simple expression after running the `SomeCodeAbout[x]`, into `g[x]`, what should I do (without manually copying the result and defining `g`)? The reason is simple, since `SomeCodeAbout[x]` could take a long time to run which is inefficient especially when `g` is used frequently.

Comment: You can use `f[x_] = …` to evaluate the right side when defining the function instead of delaying it

Comment: To store the values of `f` use `f[x_] := f[x] = SomeCodeAbout[x];`

Comment: I think memoization would be the more general approach, as Bob Hanlon mentioned. See the discussion here: [What does the construct f\[x\_\] := f\[x\] = ... mean?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/what-does-the-construct-fx-fx-mean)