# How to save previous calculation

Tags: programming

> I want to calculate the longest chain up on million applying repetily the [Collatz function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Statement_of_the_problem)  until it reach one.

I was able to solve this using the following code:

This is the definition of the function:

```
 Co[n_Integer] := If[EvenQ[n], n/2, 3 n + 1];
```

How to calculate the lenght of the chain:

```
Rco[m_Integer] := Module[{n = m},
      A = {};
      While[Co[n] != 1,
       A = Join[A, {Co[n]}];
       n = Co[n];
       ];
      Join[A, {1}]
      ]
```

and this last piece of code that calculate the lenght of everything and take the longest

```
Last[SortBy[Table[{Length[Rco[n]], n}, {n, 1, 1000000}], #[[1]] &]]
```

This is clearly a very wasteful way to compute such a lenght. Indeed my computer took several minutes to do it.

I know that since the these chains depend at some point of previus chains I could use previus calculation to reduce the amount of work my computer has to use. But I do not know how to this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor. To get started, 1) take the introductory [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: The simplest form for saving previous results would be `fn[x]:=fn[x]=code`. Also for your first function, I encourage you to read [Applying Functions Repeatedly](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionalOperations.html#23850).

Comment: also see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/what-does-the-construct-fx-fx-mean/2676#2676) for more info on the memoization mentioned by Ben Izd!