# How to remember evaluation across sessions?

Tags: evaluation, notebooks, memory, memoization

I am performing a very time-consuming symbolic calculation.
When I reopen a saved Mathematica notebook, it takes quite a long time to evaluate.

**Is there an option to tell Mathematica to remember the result of each evaluation so if the next time Mathematica is asked to calculate the same thing and parameters have not changed it won't perform calculation but take the result from memory?**

Comment: Look for `DumpSave` in the documentation.

Comment: Welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). [Edit](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: You can use `PersistentSymbol["symbol", "Notebook"]` to create a variable that gets saved into a notebook to make it persist between sessions.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit unfortunately, `PersistentSymbol["symbol", "Notebook"]` is not available in *Wolfram Cloud* or *Wolfram Engine* for me to test a complete solution based on that. Do you mind giving an example of how to use it to store the definitions of memoized functions?

Comment: @rhermans `PersistentSymbol` is just a variable. If you want to memoize function evaluations, you should use `Once` with the desired persistance location specified. Also take a look at `PersistenceLocation` to see what options you have for storing the values.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit evaluating `PersistentSymbol["symbol", "Notebook"]` in *Wolfram Cloud* give the error `PersistenceLocation::feopt` *"PersistenceLocation :Subtype NotebookPersistence of persistence location FrontEnd is not supported"*. Also with any of the other *"Supported location types"*. `{"KernelSession", "FrontEndSession", "Notebook", "ServerSession", "ServerSession", "CookieManaged", "Local", "LocalShared", "Cloud", "Installation"}`

Comment: @rhermans In the Cloud you can use `PersistentSymbol["symbol","Cloud"]` instead.

Answer (score 8):

Strategy: Use memoization and then save the relevant definition in a file at the end of your session. Next session you can recover the "memoized" definition.

## Memoization

Look at [memoization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/WriteAFunctionThatRemembersComputedValues.html) also on [other questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memoization), particularly [2639](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2639/10397). You can do this

```
f[x_]:=f[x]=ExpensiveFunctionOf[x]
```

You can then call `f[x]` and `ExpensiveFunctionOf` is evaluated only if the parameter `x` is different from previous evaluations. Otherwise, *Mathematica* will remember the output value from previous evaluations.

For example, notice how the first time `f[10]` is evaluated it takes 5 seconds (`Pause[5]`) but the second time is instantaneous because the definition of `f` now includes a specific entry for `f[10]` with the output of `ExpensiveFunctionOf[10]` as [`DownValues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html).

```
ClearAll[f,ExpensiveFunctionOf];
ExpensiveFunctionOf[x_]:=(Pause[5];Factorial[Round[x]])

f[x_]:=f[x]=ExpensiveFunctionOf[x]

AbsoluteTiming[f[10]]
(* {5.00058,3628800} *)

AbsoluteTiming[f[10]]
(* {0.00002,3628800} *)

?f
```

[image]

## DumpSave

Then, as suggested by @UlrichNeumann, you can save those definitions using [`DumpSave`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DumpSave.html) and recover them using [`Get`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Get.html)

```
DumpSave["f.mx", f]
```

## Get

```
Get["f.mx"]
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you make the title of the question a bit shorter and definitely colder? :)

Comment: @Syed You ask me or the author of the question? Also, feel free to edit the question yourself.

Comment: You of course since you have answered it well.