# How can I construct this matrix in Mathematica?

Tags: programming, code-request

[image]I would be very grateful if you could help me to construct this matrix in Mathematica.

This is the code I have so far:

```
m = 10;
a = 0;
b = 1;
h = (b - a)/(m);

x[1] = 0;
x[m] = 1;

For[
  n = 2, n <= m, n++, 
  x[n] = x[1] + n h;
]

xvalues = Table[x[i], {i, 1, m}]; 
subs = Subsets[xvalues, {Length@xvalues - 1}]; 
complements = Flatten[Complement[xvalues, #] & /@ subs]; 

d = Table[ Times @@ (1/(subs[[i]] - complements[[i]])), {i, 1, Length@subs}]; 
For[
  n = 1, n <= m, n++,
  w[n] = d[[n]];
]

aa = Table[Delete[Table[w[i]/w[n]/(x[n] - x[i]), {n, 1, m}], i], {i, 1, m}]
```

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please edit the question further and review it before submitting to the forum. Thanks.

Comment: I will do it, Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried at least defining your relationships as Mathematica functions? Can you include those as text code so it can be copy-pasted?

Comment: m = 10;

a = 0;
b = 1;
h = (b - a)/(m);
x[1] = 0;
x[m] = 1;
For[n = 2, n <= m, n++,
 x[n] = x[1] + n h;
 ]

xvalues = Table[x[i], {i, 1, m}];

subs = Subsets[xvalues, {Length@xvalues - 1}];

complements = Flatten[Complement[xvalues, #] & /@ subs];

Comment: d = Table[
   Times @@ (1/(subs[[i]] - complements[[i]])), {i, 1, Length@subs}];

For[n = 1, n <= m, n++,
 w[n] = d[[n]];
 ]
In[20]:= aa = 
 Table[Delete[Table[w[i]/w[n]/(x[n] - x[i]), {n, 1, m}], i], {i, 1, m}]

Comment: I reached here, I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Note that for simple assignments, `Do` is easier than `For`; it's exactly like `Table`, but doesn't return a list. So you can skip `d` altogether and just write `Do[ w[i] = Times @@ (1/(subs[[i]] - complements[[i]])), {i, 1, Length@subs}]`; just thought I'd share!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd write it like this. I use the trick that if I have the product over all values except $k$, I just replace the $k$th term with $1$; if I have the sum over all values except $k$, I just replace the $k$th term with $0$.

I left `x` as is, but check out `Range` and `Subdivide`; you might find something like `Clear[x]; Evaluate@Array[x, {m}] = Subdivide[a, b, m - 1]` useful, which sets all `x`'s at once.

Note: I assume there was a typo in the definition of w, and that it should have been $\prod_{k\neq j}$. If not, the code might need modification.

I also can't help but wonder: is there a typo in $L''$? The sum over $k$ includes a (relatively) constant term, $\frac{1}{x_i-x_j}$, which does not depend on $k$ and thus can come out of the sum with a factor of $n-1$ attached (`m` in the code). In any case, I translated the expressions "verbatim", matching the code to the expression as closely as possible, with the exception of using `Total` or `Times` and `Array` instead of `Sum` or `Product` for some speed.

I also use a trick for memoization, to remember explicit values: `f[x_] := (f[x] = ...)` will e.g. calculate `f[1]` only when it is first called, but then remember that explicit calculated value for later. See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/what-does-the-construct-fx-fx-mean/2676#2676).

```
m = 10;
a = 0;
b = 1;
h = (b - a)/(m);

x[1] = 0;
Do[x[i] = x[1] + i h, {i, 2, m}];

Do[w[j] = 1/(Times @@ Array[If[j == #, 1, x[j] - x[#]] &, {m}]), {j, 
  1, m}]

Lpp[j_][i_] := (Lpp[j][i] = If[j == i,
    -Total @ Array[If[i == #, 0, Lpp[#][i]] &, {m}],
    -2 (w[j]/w[i])/(x[i] - x[j])
     (Total @ Array[
         If[i == #, 
          0, (w[#]/w[i])/(x[i] - x[#]) + 1/(x[i] - x[j])] &, {m}])
    ])

D2 = Array[Lpp[#2][#1] &, {m, m}]
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if there's any unfamiliar syntax.

Comment: I am grateful for your help. Unfortunately, when I run the code, I get this message "Syntax::sntxf: "k|" cannot be followed by "->If[i==k,0,(w[k]/w[i])/(x[i]-x[k])+1/(x[i]-x[j])]"."   what does it means?

Comment: @Osama I suspect you're running an older version of Mathematica from before `|->` syntax for functions was introduced; I've edited the answer. Hopefully it's compatible now?

Comment: I am grateful for your help Dr. thorimur

Comment: Thank you Dr. thorimur for your help, your code is fantastic. Unfortunately, I got the number 9 in the numerator of some fractions but I don't know from where. can you please run this part of your code,            `m = 10;
a = 0;
b = 1;

Lpp[j_][i_] := (Lpp[j][i] = 
   If[j == i, -Total@
      Array[If[i == #, 0, Lpp[#][i]] &, {m}], -2 (w[j]/w[i])/(x[i] - 
        x[j]) (Total@
       Array[If[i == #, 
          0, (w[#]/w[i])/(x[i] - x[#]) + 1/(x[i] - x[j])] &, {m}])])

D2 = Array[Lpp[#2][#1] &, {m, m}]`        @ Thorimur