# Error: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in {-6.28293,0,\[Pi]/2}

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, warning-messages, assignment

When i try to evaulate `h` at vaule (for example 0), i get a result. When i directly plot the output of `h`, it also works, but when i try to plot `h` itself i get a very weird error:

```
f[x_] := 
 Piecewise[{{0, -\[Pi] <= x <= -\[Pi]/2}, {2 x + \[Pi], -\[Pi]/2 <= 
     x <= 0}, {\[Pi] - 2 x, 
    0 <= x <= \[Pi]/2}, {0, \[Pi]/2 <= x <= \[Pi]}}]
g[x_] := \[Pi] - 2 x
a[n_] := 2/\[Pi]*Integrate[f[x]*Cos[n*x], {x, 0, \[Pi]/2}]
h[x_] := a[0]/2 + Sum[a[i]*Cos[x*i], {i, 10}]
h[0]
Plot[{f[x], g[x], h[x] }, {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}]
```

```
"Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in {-6.28293,0,\[Pi]/2}"
```

When you take a look at the stacktrace, it shows this:

[image: Stacktrace]

Mathematica tries to replace the x from dx with -2pi?
How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Try `a[n_]:=a[n]=2/Pi*Module[{x},Integrate[f[x]*Cos[n*x],{x,0,Pi/2}]]`. The problem is that the `x` in `Plot` and the `x` in `Integrate` interfere, and one can use [`Module`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) to prevent this. I also added `...:=a[n]=...` to store values for `a` once calculated, otherwise the same computation is repeated again and again. Use `Clear[a]` to remove such stored values.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed my problem. Also thanks for the =a[n]= tip, didn't know that you could do things like that. If you post it as an answer I will accept it :)

Comment: Hi,  `:=` can lead to unexpected issues. You could either use `Module` or consider replacing all the `:=` with `=`. The pattern matching still works if you use `=`. `:=` is important if you really do not want the right hand side to evaluate right away. `:=` can also lead to performance loss because the symbolic expression on the right is computed each time the function is called. That can be lengthy when using the function with `Plot` or `NIntegrate` or `FindRoot` or other numerically intensive functions.

Comment: If you use `=` then the symbollic evaluation/conversion is done only once when the function is defined.

Comment: However, when using `=` you need to use variables that have not been assigned values. For example, it will not work the way you might want if you do `x=1;f[x_]=x;`

Comment: One other issue is that `a[n]` is evaluated symbolically and you will have to compute the limit of `a[n]` when `n` is close to zero either using `Normal@Series[a[n], {n, 0, 0}]` (I vaguely remember a case where I had to extend the series to next order to get the first order correct) or `Limit[a[n], n -> 0]` which in my past experience `Limit` was slow but the computation was quick in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `x` in `Plot` and the `x` in `Integrate` interfere.

To avoid this problem, use [`Module`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html):

```
a[n_] := 2/Pi*Module[{x},Integrate[f[x]*Cos[n*x],{x,0,Pi/2}]];
```

It can also be useful to [memoize](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/what-does-the-construct-fx-fx-mean) values, as follows:

```
a[n_] := a[n] = 2/Pi*Module[{x},Integrate[f[x]*Cos[n*x],{x,0,Pi/2}]];
```