# Complicated expressions involving hypergeometric functions

Tags: performance-tuning, special-functions, system-performance, computational-complexity, performance

This is in relation to my last post which was unanswered but I think I may have found somewhat of a workaround. I have the following preliminary definitions

```
u[z_,zb_] := z zb
v[z_,zb_] := (1-z)(1-zb)
k[a_][x_] := x^(a/2) Hypergeometric2F1[a/2, a/2, a, x]
gp[\[CapitalDelta]_][l_][z_, 
  zb_] := (-1)^
   l (k[\[CapitalDelta] + l][z]*k[\[CapitalDelta] - l][zb] + 
     k[\[CapitalDelta] + l][zb]*k[\[CapitalDelta] - l][z])/2^l

Fp[d_, \[CapitalDelta]_, l_][z_, zb_] := (v[z, zb]^d*gp[\[CapitalDelta]][l][z, zb] - u[z, zb]^d*gp[\[CapitalDelta]][l][1 - z, 1 - zb])/(u[z, zb]^d - v[z, zb]^d)

z[X_, Y_] := 1/2 + X + I Y
zb[X_, Y_] := 1/2 + X - I Y

F[d_, \[CapitalDelta]_, l_][X_, Y_] := 
 Fp[d, \[CapitalDelta], l][z[X, Y], zb[X, Y]]

(*This function finds the m, n derivative*)
fn[d_, \[CapitalDelta]_, l_][m_, n_] := 
 Re[SeriesCoefficient[
   F[d, \[CapitalDelta], l][x, y], {x, 0, m}, {y, 0, n}]]
```

What this piece of code does is that it finds me the coefficient of the $X^mY^n$ term in the series expansion of `F[d, \[CapitalDelta], l][X,Y]`. Now as you can see there are `Hypergeometric2F1` functions involved so the result is very ugly for me to paste here but you can run the code. Since it is computationally intensive and I only want a certain kind of derivatives, I define the following derivatives with immediate evaluation for the given value of `d = 0.01`. Note that I am supposed to run this calculation for a wide range of `d`. I define the following quantities

```
d = 1/100
(*Computing the derivatives*)
D40[\[CapitalDelta]_, l_] = fn[d, \[CapitalDelta], l][4, 0];
D04[\[CapitalDelta]_, l_] = fn[d, \[CapitalDelta], l][0, 4];
D20[\[CapitalDelta]_, l_] = fn[d, \[CapitalDelta], l][2, 0];
D02[\[CapitalDelta]_, l_] = fn[d, \[CapitalDelta], l][0, 2];
D42[\[CapitalDelta]_, l_] = fn[d, \[CapitalDelta], l][4, 2];
D24[\[CapitalDelta]_, l_] = fn[d, \[CapitalDelta], l][2, 4];
D22[\[CapitalDelta]_, l_] = fn[d, \[CapitalDelta], l][2, 2];
D06[\[CapitalDelta]_, l_] = fn[d, \[CapitalDelta], l][0, 6];
D60[\[CapitalDelta]_, l_] = fn[d, \[CapitalDelta], l][6, 0];
```

Now the derivatives are evaluation and I construct the following sum

```
sum[\[CapitalDelta]_, l_] = c[4, 0] D40[\[CapitalDelta], l] +
  c[0, 4] D04[\[CapitalDelta], l] + 
  c[2, 0] D20[\[CapitalDelta], l] + 
  c[0, 2] D02[\[CapitalDelta], l] + 
  c[4, 2] D42[\[CapitalDelta], l] + 
  c[2, 4] D24[\[CapitalDelta], l] + 
  c[2, 2] D22[\[CapitalDelta], l] + 
  c[0, 6] D06[\[CapitalDelta], l] + D60[\[CapitalDelta], l]
```

The coefficients `c[i,j]` are to be determined using `LinearOptimization` later on but the problem that I am facing is that for large values of `\[CapitalDelta]` and `l` it takes a lot of time to run. This has to do with the fact that the `D`s themselves take a lot of time to evaluate for large `\[CapitalDelta]` and `l`. For example, running `sum[12,12]//AbsoluteTiming` gives me 105.544 seconds as the time required to run this command, which is a lot since I will run the code for values as high as `\[CapitaDelta] = 20` and `l = 24`.

Is there a way to make the computation shorter? I am struggling with this for the past two weeks with no avail. I have restored to asking here after much frustration. Kindly help me on making it a bit shorter. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I guess you are doing some computations of conformal bootstrap. It's quite consuming to directly calculate the derivatives of conformal blocks (except for dim=1). It's more practical to use the rational approximations of conformal blocks instead.

Comment: If you are only working with examples, you can cache the intermediate result by the memorization trick, see e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/what-does-the-construct-fx-fx-mean

Comment: Hi @Lacia thanks for commenting. What do you mean working with 'examples'? I am trying to get the bootstrap bounds in Rattazzi et. al.'s 2008 paper, "Bounding scalar operator dim..." which I think you must be aware of. The authors claimed in this paper and the follow up paper "Universal constraints on conformal operator dimensions" that all calculations were done in Mathematica. Although I am using a personal computer with not much computational power. Is that the problem?

Comment: Also just to mention, I was able to solve the issue of time with by using `Compile` but if I increase the number of basis elements then it becomes difficult.

Comment: I do not have too much practice with numerical bootstrap. You might find this notebook helpful https://gitlab.com/bootstrapcollaboration/blocks-mathematica